# Why doesn't gcc -Wformat warn about printf %d on an unsigned int?

Tags: c, gcc, gcc-warning, format-specifiers, format-string

The following program has undefined behavior:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    unsigned int x = -100; // This is fine, becomes UINT_MAX - 100
    printf("%d\n", x); // This is undefined behavior.
    return 0;
}
```

> C99 7.19.6.1p8 states %d expects an int argument.
>
> C99 7.19.6.1p9 states "If any argument is not the correct type for the
>   corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is
>   **undefined**."

However, gcc `-Wformat` (which is included with `-Wall`) will not complain about the above program, why? Is this a bug, or a deliberate omission?

From the gcc manpage:

```
-Wformat
```

Check calls to `"printf"` and `"scanf"`, etc., to make sure that the arguments supplied have types appropriate to the format string specified, and that the conversions specified in the format string make sense

Comment: C99 6.3.1.3p3 says conversion of unsigned to signed is implementation defined.

Comment: @user315052: There is no conversion; the representation of `x` (an `unsigned int` object) is interpreted as if it were of type `int`.

Comment: @KeithThompson: I think there is because of C99 7.15.1.1p2, last sentence, where it makes an exception for signed/unsigned when converting argument types through the `va_arg` macro.

Comment: @KeithThompson there is no conversion emitted in the code only because the function is varargs.  If the function **was** declared to take `int`, the call would be legal.  So why should gcc be expected to issue a warning for a legal case?

Comment: @user315052: I just read that paragraph; it doesn't imply that there's a *conversion*.

Comment: @AndyRoss: gcc of course isn't *required* to issue a warning, but it might reasonably do so since, if the value of `x` exceeds `INT_MAX`, the behavior is undefined. Arguments of type `int` and `unsigned int` are interchangeable *only* for values representable in both types.

Comment: @KeithThompson: It does deny it being *undefined behavior*. So it must be one of *defined*, *unspecified*, or *implementation defined*. The whole section was about converting types through `va_arg`. Since the standard doesn't specify the behavior in anyway other than through unsigned to signed conversion, I concluded implementation defined via that conversion. But, YMMV.

Comment: @user315052: It's defined if "one type is a signed integer type, the other type is the corresponding unsigned integer
type, *and the value is representable in both types*"; in the example, `UINT_MAX-100` exceeds `INT_MAX`. And the section says nothing about conversions.

Comment: Compilers aren't mandated to warn for anything that is UB in the standard. If this compiler is coded such that it behaves well in this case then there's no problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

My best guess is that the warning is skipped because the UB is arguably invoked by the *value* and not merely by the type. `va_arg` allows the signedness to mismatch as long as the value is representable in both the signed and unsigned type. However, `printf` and friends are not specified in terms of `va_arg` and the standard states that any type mismatch results in UB, but this is probably a bug in the standard. Otherwise, `printf("%x",1);` would invoke UB. See my question on the topic:

[Does printf("%x",1) invoke undefined behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4664100/does-printfx-1-invoke-undefined-behavior)

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense as 6.2.5p6 requires int and unsigned int to use the same amount of storage. Even though printf %d on an unsigned is technically undefined, there's no plausible reason for it to cause real issues.

Comment: The standard doesn't say that `printf()` uses `<stdarg.h>`, but the fact that you can construct a pointer to the `printf()` function can call through it implies at least some commonality in the argument-passing mechanism.

Comment: GCC 5.0 has such a warning now: [`-Wformat-signedness`](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=60194) (enabled by `-Wformat`).

Comment: experimenting here http://rextester.com/live/CCQJKP79309 suggests that -Wformat-signedness works but is not included in -Wformat

Comment: The whole point of being a separate option is that it doesn't.