# why in o/p the values of i is different

Tags: c

Why i am getting the different values of i.

```
#include <stdio.h>
void pri(int,int);
int main()
{
    float a=3.14;
    int i=99;
    pri(a,i);
    getch();
}
void pri(int a,int i)
{
    printf("a=%f i=%d\n",a,i);
    printf("i=%d a=%f\n",i,a);
}
```

Comment: Please tell us a bit more, I can't understand your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to explain your comment's question:

```
printf("a=%f i=%d\n", a, i);
```

will evaluate to something like:

```
printf("a=");
printf(/*next arguments up to size of float*/ a, i);
printf(" i=");
printf(/*...decimal*/ /*whatever is on the stack, because a and i are already consumed*/);
```

you can rescue your function with: 'printf("a=%f i=%d\n", (float)a, i);'

Answer (score 3):

You declared `a` as an int, but you are using `%f` so it should be declared as a float:

```
void pri(float a, int i)
{
    printf("a=%f i=%d\n", a, i);
    printf("i=%d a=%f\n", i, a);
}
```

If you have an incorrect type you get undefined behaviour. The specification for `printf` reads (7.19.6.1 paragraph 9):

> If a conversion speciﬁcation is invalid, the behavior is undeﬁned. **If any argument is not the correct type for the corresponding conversion speciﬁcation, the behavior is undeﬁned.**

Emphasis mine.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4664100/does-printfx-1-invoke-undefined-behavior)

Comment: ya i know that's the correction for dis program.....but i am not getting why both consecutive printf statements giving different values of i.

Comment: @TusharGaurav: Because as you can see from my edit, it's specified as **undefined behaviour**. Anything can happen when you invoke UB, including incorrect results being displayed.