# Why does the sizeof responses differently to %f?

Tags: c, gcc, escaping, sizeof

Why am I not getting the same value as I get with `%d` and not with `%f`?

```
void main()
{ 
   int arr;
   printf("%f",sizeof(arr));
}
```

Output:  `2.168831`

```
void main()
{ 
   int arr;
   printf("%d",sizeof(arr));
}
```

output: `4`

Comment: `printf("%f",sizeof(arr));` is undefined, second don't use `void main` use `int main`

Comment: Because `%f` expects a `double`, whereas you are passing it a `size_t`. That's undefined behavior.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan why do you say its undefined? Do you mean that %f only expects double value?

Comment: @Shanpriya read below updated answer.

Comment: @Shanpriya A good reference [C Printf and Scanf Reference](http://wpollock.com/CPlus/PrintfRef.htm)

Comment: **You lied to the compiler.** You stated "I'll give you a double" with "%f" but then gave an unsigned integral type as the argument. That's *undefined behavior* and compilers are allowed to even  refuse to compile such code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sizeof` returns `size_t` but `printf("%f",...` tells `printf` that the next argument has type `double`.  `size_t` has a different layout in memory from `double` so `printf` incorrectly interprets this argument.

As Grijesh points out, the correct format specifier to use would be `%zu` but if you really want to use `%f`

```
printf("%f",(double)sizeof(arr));
```

would work

Comment: and correct format string is `%zu` for sizeof (in mcrosoft use `%lu`)

Comment: so %zu is used to define sizeof and even %d is a wrong way to declare?

Comment: @simonc I think add `"If a conversion specification is invalid, the behavior is undefined"` from [`C standard (6.5.2.2 paragraph 6)`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4664100/does-printfx-1-invoke-undefined-behavior) OP has doubt as he commented to me.

Answer (score 4):

To give a bit more of an explanation, it's because `printf()` is a variadic function, and the types of the arguments are not known until the function runs and determines what they are from the format string. This means that the normal implicit conversions will not occur.

For instance, if you do something like:

```
void myfunc(double d) {
    /*  Do something with d  */
}

int main(void) {
    int n = 5;
    myfunc(n);
    return 0;
}
```

then the compiler knows that `myfunc()` takes an argument of type `double`, and therefore can and will implicitly convert `n` from `int` to `double` before passing the parameter.

When you do:

```
int main(void) {
    double f = 5.5;
    printf("%d\n", f);  /*  WARNING: buggy code  */
    return 0;
}
```

the compiler has no idea what type `printf()` is expecting until it runs and makes sense of the `%d` in the format string. So, all it can do is pass the `double` argument as a `double`, and when `printf()` runs and sees the `%d`, it'll interpret it as an `int` and things will start going horribly wrong when it misinterprets the bit pattern (and, in this case, probably the size of the argument, as well, throwing it off for any other arguments which come after it).

This is, among other things, the reason why these functions are one of the rare occasions where casts to `void *` are actually necessary in C, since pointers to different types of objects are allowed to be different sizes, and since `%p` expects a `void *`, you have to pass it a `void *`, and not a pointer to any other object type.

Note, though, that modern compilers can be smart, and they know how standard C functions work, so they can just be informed about the standard behavior of functions like `printf()` such that they can give you warnings about mismatched argument types like this, although they won't actually fix them for you.

Answer (score 3):

`sizeof` operator returns `` `size_t `` You should use `%zu` format specifier with `printf()`

Note that `size_t` is `unsigned`, `signed` sizes can be represented by `ssize_t`.

Both of these types are defined in the `stddef.h` header

**§7.21.6.1 p9 of the C11 standard** says

> If a conversion specification is invalid, the behavior is undefined. If any argument is
>   not the correct type for the corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is
>   undefined.