# bit shift for unsigned int, why negative?

Tags: c++, c, bit-shift, unsigned

Code:

```
unsigned int i = 1<<31;
printf("%d\n", i);
```

Why the out put is `-2147483648`, a negative value?

---

**Updated question:**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    int i = 1<<31;
    unsigned int j = 1<<31;
    printf("%u, %u\n", i, j);
    printf("%d, %d\n", i, j);

    return 0;
}
```

The above print:

```
2147483648, 2147483648
-2147483648, -2147483648
```

So, does this means, signed int & unsigned int have the same bit values, the difference is how you treat the 31st bit when convert it to a number value?

Comment: because you use `%d`.  use `%u` for `unsigned int`.

Comment: undefined behaviour..

Comment: Because %d is the format character for "signed int". If you tell the computer it's a signed int and give it an unsigned int that is too big to fit into an int, then it's entirely your fault.

Comment: @gnasher729 Or it's the language's fault for not understanding its own types and letting you print a type as if it were another type without any complaints.

Comment: @endolith `printf()` is part of the standard library, not of the language itself.

Comment: `1<<31` is a `int` and UB when `INT_MAX<1UL<<31`, which is the case when `int is 32 bit or shorter. Better use `1UL<<31` which uses `long` which is at least 32 bit and `unsigned`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`%d` prints the `int` version of the `unsigned int i`. Try `%u` for `unsigned int`.

```
printf("%u\n", i);
```

---

```
int main(){
    printf("%d, %u",-1,-1);
    return 0;
}
```

`Output: -1, 4294967295`

i.e The way a signed integer is stored and how it gets converted to signed from unsigned or vice-versa will help you. Follow [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations).

To answer your updated question, its how the system represents them i.e in a 2's complement (as in the above case where 
    `-1 =2's complement of 1 = 4294967295`.

Comment: Quoted in your example: `printf("%d, %u",-1,-1);` is undefined behavior.

Comment: I checked it in codepad. But I hope you get the essence.

Comment: @thepace I checked the link to wiki, it's great ! Now I understand the history of signed number representation by computer, and why 2'complement is widely used in now days. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

`printf("%d\n", i);` invokes [UB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4664100/does-printfx-1-invoke-undefined-behavior). `i` is `unsigned int` and you try to print it as `signed int`. Writing `1 << 31` instead of `1U << 31` is undefined too.

Print it as:

```
printf("%u\n", i);
```

or

```
printf("%X\n", i);
```

About your updated question, it also invokes UB for the very same reasons (If you use '1U' instead of `1`, then for the reason that an `int` is initialized with `1U << 31` which is out of range value. If an `unsigned` is initialized with out of range value, modular arithmetic come into picture and remainder is assigned. For `signed` the behavior is undefined.)

**Understanding the behavior on your platform**
On your platform, int appears to be 4 byte. When you write something like `1 << 31`, it converts to bit patters `0x80000000` on your machine.

Now when you try to print this pattern as signed, it prints signed interpretation which is -2<sup>31</sup> (AKA [INT_MIN](http://www.hardtoc.com/archives/119)) in 2s completement system. When you print this as unsigned, you get expected 2<sup>31</sup> as output.

---

**Learnings**
1. Use `1U << 31` instead of `1 << 31`
2. Always use correct print specifiers in printf.
3. Pass correct argument types to [variadic functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function).
4. Be careful when implicit typecast (unsigned -> signed, wider type -> narrow type) takes place. If possible, avoid such castings completely.

Comment: Hi downvoter, please leave your kind comment about what is wrong in the answer.

Comment: " When you write something like `1 << 31`, it converts to bit patters 0x80000000 on your machine." No it is UB, the compiler may generate something completely different, because UB is UB. `1U<<32==0x80000000` when `UINT_MAX>=0x80000000`, without UB.

Answer (score 4):

Use '`%u`' for `unsigned int`

```
 printf("%u\n", i);
```

.......................................................

Response to updated question: any sequence of bits can be interpreted as a signed or unsigned value.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
printf("%u\n", i);
```

By using `%d` specifier, printf expects argument as `int` and it typecast to `int`.
So, use `%u` for `unsigned int`.

Answer (score 3):

You are not doing the shift operation on an `unsigned` but on a `signed int`.

- `1` is `signed`.
- the shift operation then shifts into the sign bit of
  that `signed` (assuming that `int` is 32 bit wide), that is already undefined behavior
- then you assign whatever the compiler thinks he wants for that value to an `unsigned`.
- then you print an `unsigned` as a signed, again no defined behavior.

Answer (score 2):

`%u` is for unsigned int.
`%d` is for signed int.

in your programs output :

```
2147483648, 2147483648     (output for unsigned int)
-2147483648, -2147483648   (output for signed int )
```