# When trying to print UINT_MAX I get -1

Tags: c, uint

When trying to print 'UINT_MAX' all I get it -1, why is this? It's the only thing I have in my 'main()', a printf statement that prints 'UINT_MAX'

Comment: Please show your code (preferably a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)).

Answer (score 2):

You used the `%d` format code, which interprets its argument as a signed `int`. You're on a two's complement system, so `UINT_MAX` (`0xFFFFFFFF`), interpreted as a signed `int`, is equal to `-1`. If you want to print it interpreted as `unsigned`, use `%u`.

Comment: It's not "interpreted as signed int". It's just undefined behavior. Your format specifiers must match the type you're trying to print.

Comment: @R.. "format specifiers must match the _promoted_ type" and using `"%d"` or `"%u"` for either `int` or `unsigned` is a specified exception if the value is representable in both types.  else its UB to use mis-matched specifier/type.

Comment: @chux: `printf` actually lacks any such exception for when the value is representable in both types. You're thinking of `va_arg`, perhaps.

Comment: @R.. I'm thinking of C11 §6.5.2.2 6 "... , the behavior is undeﬁned, except for the following cases:
— one promoted type is a signed integer type, the other promoted type is the corresponding unsigned integer type, and the value is representable in both types; ...".  allow using `"%d"` or `"%u"` for either `int` or `unsigned`.

Comment: @chux: That text is about missing prototypes and has nothing to do with `printf`.

Comment: @R.. The larger section specifies "... If the function is deﬁned with a type that includes a prototype, and either the prototype ends with an ellipsis (, ...)  " which is certainly `printf()`.  Yet I doubt we we agree on this matter here - the section is fairly open to interpretation given its complexity..  Perhaps a question for SO, if it has not all ready been made.

Comment: @chux: It has. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4664100/does-printfx-1-invoke-undefined-behavior Note that I seem to have mistakenly quoted the same passage you just did, which does not specify exceptions for the variadic case, just the no-prototype case. The variadic case is governed by 7.16.1.1 The va_arg macro, but `printf` is not defined in terms of `va_arg`.

Comment: @R.. the prototype of printf has "...", its doesn't simple means that it's use va_arg ?

Comment: @Stargateur: No; formally, it's simply part of the language.

Answer (score 0):

You can print it with printf()

```
printf("%u\n", UINT_MAX);
```

You need to use `u` specifier, [man printf](https://linux.die.net/man/3/printf).

Why you get -1 with `d` specifier? It's because of how work a signed integer in memory.

`unsigned integer` start at 0, in memory it a simple binary system.

decimal => binary

- 1 => 1
- 2 => 10
- 8 => 1000
- 255 => 11111111

signed integer use a bit to be interpreted as a negative number, it's confusing because the max value of an unsigned int when it is interpreted like an int is -1.

example with 8 bit integer:

- -1 => 11111111
- -128 => 10000000
- -9 => 11110111

Like you see, the first bit is used to be the sign bit.

Try with this [site](http://www.free-test-online.com/binary/signed_converter.html)