# short x = -123; printf("%x\n", x>>3);

Tags: c

```
short x = -123;
unsigned short y = -123;

printf("%x\n", x>>3);
printf("%x\n", y>>3);
```

The result was

```
fffffff0
1ff0
```

I don't understand the first result because short is 2 bytes but the result was 4 bytes.

Comment: Shorts get auto-promoted to int just about anywhere you use them.

Comment: It got promoted

Comment: then why wasn't the second one promoted?

Comment: for [informations](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/) the modifier for a short in `printf` is `h` as `%hx`

Comment: it was promoted because it could not guess the length of the integer you wanted to print, and went for a regular `int` by default, as no modifier was specified

Comment: @alkanian The second one is promoted as well. However, it's an unsigned type, so there's no sign extension to see.

Comment: What's the intention of the right shifts? Logical shift or arithmetic shift?

Answer (score 1):

The `%x` format specifier expects an `unsigned int` argument. Passing any other type of argument ([even `int`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4664100/does-printfx-1-invoke-undefined-behavior)) causes undefined behaviour.

You could modify your code to:

```
printf("%x\n", (unsigned int)(x>>3));
printf("%x\n", (unsigned int)(y>>3));
```

For `x >> 3`, first of all `x` undergoes integer promotion. This turns `(short)-123` into `(int)-123` because promotions are value-preserving.

Then `-123 >> 3` causes implementation-defined behaviour. Probably your implementation defines it as an arithmetic right shift on the 2's complement representation in 32-bit integers:

```
-123:         11111111111111111111111110000101
-123 >> 3: 11111111111111111111111111110000
```

which is `-16` in 2's complement.

Finally, `(unsigned int)-16` is defined as meaning `UINT_MAX - 15`. `0xFFFFFFFF - 15` gives `0xFFFFFFF0`.

---

For the `unsigned short y = -123;` line, `-123` is converted to `unsigned short`, giving value for `y` on your system of `USHRT_MAX - 122` which is `65413`. Then for `y >> 3`, this value is promoted to `int`, retaining the value `65413`. The definition of right-shift for positive numbers is to divide by `2` that many times. `65413/8` gives `8176` which is `1FF0` in hex.

Comment: Thank you. but the definition of right-shit for positive numbers and negative numbers are different? Because -123/8=-15.375 but the result was -16, not -15. Is it different for negative number?

Comment: @alkanian I cover this in my answer; right-shift of negative numbers is *implementation-defined* which means your compiler must choose and document a behaviour. Right-shift of positive numbers is defined as repeated integer division by 2.

Comment: Okay, what I want to know is in case of arithmetic right shift, negative numbers round down to floor? like -15.375->-16

Comment: @alkanian you need to read your compiler's documentation to find out. Normally the behaviour is as I described in my answer, in terms of bits and not values

Answer (score 1):

> I don't understand the first result because short is 2 bytes but the result was 4 bytes.

First of all, the `>>` operator causes implicit *integer promotion* of both operands to `int`, unless they weren't already of a larger type. The resulting type of the expression is that of the promoted left operand.

Even without the shift operator, all small integer types that are passed to variable-argument functions such as printf, undergo a similar form of implicit integer promotion (the default argument promotion rule) to `int`.

This is the reasons why you get 4 bytes.

As for why the values are printed in the way they are, see the answer by M.M. Your code is using the incorrect format specifiers and relies on various forms of poorly-specified behavior, so anything can happen.

Answer (score -2):

Not specifying a modifier for your format in `printf` indicate you want the default `int` to be printed ( regardless of the length of the value you are passing ).

you can refer to this [`printf` reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/) , especially the specifier list to indicate to `printf` what is the length you desire.
In your case you wanted a `"%hx"` format.

Comment: `%x` is for `unsigned int`, not `int`