# Why didn't GCC optimize this 'printf' to 'puts'?

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, compiler-optimization

Here is my test code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

static inline void foo(int a){
    printf("%x\n", a);  
}

int main(void){
    foo(0x1234);    
    return 0;
}
```

I thought GCC should realize that `a` is a literal integer, and optimize to code like this:

```
puts("1234");
```

But I got the following assembly code:

```
│0x8048341 <main+17>     push   $0x1234                                        
│0x8048346 <main+22>     push   $0x80484e0                                  
│0x804834b <main+27>     push   $0x1                                        
│0x804834d <main+29>     call   0x8048310 <__printf_chk@plt>
```

There exists a lot of such code in my project, because I always believed that GCC would optimize for me, and even in some context where could simply use 'write()', I insisted using `printf`, because I thought I would gain benefit from its buffer mechanism.

Now I feel regret, for the overhead of paring a format string will kill any gain I have. These codes in my project are quite low-level, and they might cause the performance bottleneck.

Comment: [Premature optimization is the root of all evil](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization)

Comment: Have you *measured* the performance?

Comment: Relying on compiler to magically optimize things for you is usually a hopeless practice.

Comment: I don't think a compiler is *ever* allowed to optimize a library call away. You could link a library where `printf()` has side-effects the compiler can't know about at the compile stage.

Comment: Your code invoke UB, `%x` is for `unsigned int`.

Comment: @FelixPalmen No, the compiler can because `printf()` is define by C standard.

Comment: I believe that requiring GCC to be able to parse *all* the printf formats is unrealistic. Recognising that no format is present is simple, parsing an eventual format is not.

Comment: @MargaretBloom when the format is a string literal and the argument can be traced as a constant expression, it seems realistic to do compile-time detection

Comment: I'd conjecture that in real code the occurrences of this is somewhat limited; if you wanted to output 1234 you could have just written `puts("1234");` instead of jumping through hoops.

Comment: @Stargateur I have test using `%d`, and the same result.

Comment: @weiweishuo Have you found any cases where GCC optimizes `printf`? Maybe it's not considered an important optimization. Are you really calling `printf` with literal arguments in an inner loop where the performance is critical?

Comment: @Stargateur Actually, passing an `int` for `%x` may be well-defined, as `va_arg` allows mixing signedness (7.15.1.1 in C99). GCC and Clang seem to agree with this interpretation, as they don't warn even with `-Wformat=2`.

Comment: Lesson learned: Instead of "I thought", go for "I tested" next time. It's easy to point at a piece of code and figure out that this particular construct should have been optimized to something. It's actually hard to think of all possible future code someone might write and implement optimizations for it. Also, I don't think you'd like a compiler that optimizes everything since it would be giant and incredibly slow.

Comment: @weiweishuo I didn't tell that it was going to solve your problem. I agree with Barmar. This optimization is not important. IO will be always slow. If you want performance don't use IO. `printf()` or `puts()` are similar. P.S: try `printf("0x1234\n");`.

Comment: @Fanael Thank, my compiler don't show any warning, that explain why. But it's better to use `unsigned int` anyway.

Comment: @M.M GCC still needs to figure the correct string to output based on the format. It's surely possible to implement this optimisation but maybe it was regarded as not worth the troubles of maintaining a duplicate of `printf`. Maybe in a couple of years we'll get it? :)

Comment: @FelixPalmen yes it can. That's why gcc has `-fno-builtin` to disable the optimization of functions like [`malloc, memcpy, memset, pow, printf, sincos, stpcpy, stpncpy...`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.2.2/gcc/Other-Builtins.html#Other-Builtins)

Comment: `printf` is slower than `puts` because `printf` needs to parse the format string even if there is no format directive in it while `puts` prints its content verbatim. And both use the same buffer; so if buffering is your need, `puts` is also adequate. Note: that you hope on such an optimisation is very highly improbable (compiler would  needs to know to much about your code and needs).

Comment: `and optimize to code like this: puts("1234");` ... gcc does not have AI yet. You expect too much from optimization.

Comment: @Fanael if you read the standard strictly, then `printf("%x", 1);` is UB but `printf("%lx", -1);` is not UB.  Personally I interpret this as the specification of printf being defective.  [Link to thread on the topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4664100/does-printfx-1-invoke-undefined-behavior)

Answer (score 6):

> These codes in my project are quite low-level, and they might cause the performance bottleneck.

First off, I can assuage your fears that this is not possible. The overhead of console I/O is *tremendous* (relatively speaking), so that will always be the bottleneck in your code, no matter what means you use to do it.

> I thought gcc should realize that `a` is a literal integer, and optimize to code like this:
>
> ```
> puts("1234");
> ```

Clearly it doesn't. GCC (and Clang) [*does* perform an optimization where `printf("...\n");` is transformed into `puts("...");`](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/061c331bec278599a7b60609ae46260d17878662/gcc/gimple-fold.c#L3230), as you can see [here](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,source:%27%23include+%3Cstdio.h%3E%0A%0Avoid+Print(void)%0A%7B%0A++++printf(%22Hello,+world%5Cn%22)%3B%0A%7D%0A%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:25.518341307814996,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g63,filters:(b:%270%27,commentOnly:%270%27,directives:%270%27,intel:%270%27),options:%27-xc+-m32+-O2%27,source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+gcc+6.3+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:41.14832535885168,l:%274%27,m:100,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang391,filters:(b:%270%27,commentOnly:%270%27,directives:%270%27,intel:%270%27),options:%27-xc+-m32+-O2%27,source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+clang+3.9.1+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%232)%27,t:%270%27)),k:33.33333333333333,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4), but this only happens when you use *string literals* with `printf`. The optimizer doesn't (currently) peek into the format string, parse it, and optimize around it. You called `printf`, so you get `printf`.

Compiler optimizations aren't *guaranteed*, so you shouldn't write code that *relies* on them without first verifying that the desired optimizations are in fact being applied under all circumstances in which you are interested (including code variations, compiler versions, target platforms, etc.).

If you'd like to suggest this as a possible improvement for the GCC optimizer, you can suggest an enhancement on [their Bugzilla](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/). But don't hold your breath on it being implemented any time soon. The logic required to implement this type of optimization is not really worth the effort, considering the real-world performance improvements that could be expected are minimal at best (see above).

In the meantime, if you *absolutely* require this optimization with minimal changes to your code, then you can use [some macro hackery](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Stringizing.html#Stringizing):

```
#define STRINGIFY_INTERNAL(x)  #x
#define STRINGIFY(x)           STRINGIFY_INTERNAL(x)

#define foo(a)                 puts(STRINGIFY(a))
```

This does produce the desired output:

```
.LC0:
        .string "0x1234"
MyFunction:
        sub     esp, 24
        push    OFFSET FLAT:.LC0
        call    puts
        xor     eax, eax
        add     esp, 28
        ret
```

Comment: It turns out that clang will optimize `const char fmt[] =  = {'h', 'i', '\n', 0};` / `printf(fmt);` into a `puts`.  https://godbolt.org/g/aTQRKX But for gcc, it does literally have to be a string literal.  (At least indirectly; `const char*fmt = "hi\n";` and then passing that to printf optimizes, as long as there are no other args to printf.)

Comment: Interesting observation, @Peter. I had not considered that variation, and I'm honestly kind of surprised that GCC's pattern-matching optimization does not work there.

Comment: I was surprised too, but it makes some sense.  I guess it doesn't look at char-arrays or their initializers as string constants, since it would have to check that they contain only a single `0` byte at the end.  You can kind of see this in the asm output where gcc uses separate `.byte` directives instead of a `.asciz`, but clang notices the string-like nature and emits `.asciz` as well as doing the puts optimization.

Comment: Hmm, I wonder if there are any real-life missed-optimizations with `strlen()` or `strchr()` on char arrays instead of strings?  This printf/puts one seems pretty artificial for a char array.

Comment: Gcc 12.1 optimises to puts too, Peter. In fact it happens since 9.1.

Comment: Seems like they do peek into the format string, parse it and optimize around *sometimes*. https://godbolt.org/z/hq38EWvTz

Answer (score 2):

A conforming library implementation could include functions beyond those defined by the Standard, which would change the way standard functions behave.  For example, a library might include a `__select_alternate_digits` function that, when invoked, would cause succeeding calls to `printf` to display numbers using something other than the normal digits.

With such a library, given the code:

```
#include <stdio.h> // Could legitimately include functions that aren't
                  // defined by the Standard, but which start with __.

int main(void)
{
  __select_alternate_digits("⁰¹²³⁴⁵⁶⁷⁸⁹");
  printf("%d",123);
  __select_alternate_digits(0); // Reset to default set      
}
```

the call to `__select_alternate_digits` might cause the above program to output "¹²³" rather than "123".  If the compiler bundled its own `printf` function, it could know that its behavior wasn't going to be affected by any other function calls.  If it's using an outside library, however, then unless the program is completely free of any calls to functions the compiler knows nothing about, a quality compiler should assume those functions might have effects the compiler can't predict.

Comment: This doesn't really explain anything: `printf("123\n");` [_is_ replaced by a call to `puts`](https://godbolt.org/g/Gr9uqZ), while the OP's code isn't, despite the original function being one and the same: `printf`, so the compiler does know something about it.

Comment: @Ruslan: It would be unusual for implementations of printf to do any kind of translation with strings that don't contain `%`.  It think gcc is perhaps being a bit presumptuous in assuming that they won't, but the further it goes into the realm of non-trivial format specifiers, the greater the likelihood of trouble.  I did, however, forget another point: one of the uses of code containing printf with non-trivial format strings is to *test* printf implementations.  If a programmer writes `printf("Hello");` it's likely the programmer is more interested in outputting `Hello\n` than...

Comment: ...in testing whether `printf` can handle such strings correctly.  But given `printf("%d\n",-2147483647-1);` a programmer may not be interested in outputting `-2147483648\n` but rather in confirming that a particular `printf` implementation handles the `INT_MIN` case correctly.  Having the compiler do the formatting itself would undermine that goal.

Comment: re: testing `printf` or `memcpy` or whatever implementations: use `gcc -fno-builtin-printf`.

Comment: glibc `printf` *does* allow customizations by registering new conversions, or even overriding standard conversion specifiers.  (https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Customizing-Printf.html).  So in a GNU system, it's only safe to transform `printf` calls when the format string contains no conversions, because stuff that runs before `main` could have changed the behaviour for `%x`.

Comment: @PeterCordes: Other library versions of printf might offer additional features, like the ability to register conversions that use something other than `%`, though I don't know of any.  In my own embedded code, I sometimes use a formatting function which uses codes `\200` to `\377` for formatting (more compact and easier to parse than % strings if code doesn't need to output anything that isn't ASCII) but don't call it `printf`.  In any case, what do you think about the point in my comment re testing `printf` implementations.

Comment: Like I commented earlier, if you want to test the library `printf`, use [`gcc -fno-builtin-printf`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C-Dialect-Options.html).  Leaving out useful but safe optimizations to standard functions doesn't make sense for gcc or clang, especially not for testability because it's easy to make the compiler not use any pre-conceived ideas about what a function with that name should do.  (This optimization would not be 100% safe in GNU C, and also not be very useful.)