# tilde operator query in C working differently

Tags: c, operators, tilde

I came across this question.
What is the output of this C code?

```
#include <stdio.h>

    int main()
    {
        unsigned int a = 10;
        a = ~a;
        printf("%d\n", a);
    }
```

I know what tilde operator do, now 10 can be represented as 1010 in binary, and if i bitwise not it, i get 0101, so i do not understand the output -11. Can anyone explain?

Comment: How many bits in `a`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *bitwise negation* will **not** result in `0101`. Note that an int contains **at least 16 bits**. So, for 16 bits, it will generate:

```
 a = 0000 0000  0000 1010
~a = 1111 1111  1111 0101
```

So we expect to see a large number (with 16 bits that would be 65'525), but you use **`%d` as format specifier**. This means you interpret the integer as a *signed* integer. Now signed integers use the [***two-complement representation*** [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement). This means that every integers where the highest bit is set, is negative, and furthermore that in that case the value is equal to `-1-(~x)`, so `-11`. In case the specifier was **`%u`**, then the format would be an *unsigned* integer.

**EDIT**: like @R. says, `%d` is only well defined for unsigned integers, if these are in the range of the *signed* integers as well, outside it depends on the implementation.

Comment: I just read the article. Makes sense. I am just trying to understand how the output is -11. Give me a minute, and I ll accept the answer once i understand

Comment: i think you mean 'SO -11'

Comment: The choice of `%d` causes undefined behavior. `%d` can only be used with an unsigned argument when the value of the argument is in the range of `signed int`. Here, it's not.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: I'm not sure what you're trying to say. `va_arg` has equivalent language that the signedness can mismatch if the value fits. Strictly speaking, `printf` does not use `va_arg` but is specified on its own and does not include such an exception, but it seems to be generally agreed that this is just an oversight and not intentional; see my related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4664100/does-printfx-1-invoke-undefined-behavior

Comment: Regarding the answer's edit: "depends on the implementation" suggests that the behavior is implementation-defined or unspecified, but it's outright undefined.

Comment: @R..: Ah, never mind, 6.5.2.2 6 applies only “If the expression that denotes the called function has a type that does not include a prototype.”

Answer (score 3):

It's  undefined behaviour, since `"%d"` is for signed integers;  for unsigned  ones, use `"%u"`.

Otherwise, note that negative values are often represented as a two's complement;  So `-a == (~a)+1`, or the other way round: `(~a) == -a -1`. Hence, `(~10)` is the same as `-10-1`, which is `-11`.

Answer (score 1):

The format specifier for an unsigned decimal integer is `%u`. `%d` is for a signed decimal integer.

`printf("%d\n", a)` is interpreting `a` as a signed int. You want `printf("%u\n", a)`.

Comment: how will even a signed int return -11?

Comment: @NameSake: because signed integers use *2-complement* representation.