# Printf in unsigned short int and unsigned int using %d

Tags: c, printf, short, unsigned-integer, integer-promotion

Why in second printf when using %d I am not getting -1?

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    unsigned int u=-1;
    unsigned short int y=-1;
    printf("%d %u\n",u,u);
    printf("%d %u",y,y);
}
```

Comment: Use `%hu` and `%hd` to print `short` accurately.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4664100/does-printfx-1-invoke-undefined-behavior

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `int` is 32-bit, `short` is 16-bit, and the architecture uses two's complement: When you set `y=-1` the conversion from signed to unsigned yields `65535`. When `y` is passed to `printf` it is promoted back to `int`, but this time the value `65535` is representable, thus `printf` will print `65535`.

Answer (score 2):

The variable `u` is declared as having the type `unsigned int`.

```
unsigned int u=-1;
```

So you may not use the conversion specifier `%d` with this variable because the value of the `u` is not representable in an object of the type `int`. You have to use the conversion specifier `%u`.

As for your question then the variable `y` has the type `unsigned short` and its value as an unsigned value after the integer promotion to the type `int` can be represented in an object of the type `int`. So the positive value is outputted.

In this declaration

```
unsigned short int y=-1;
```

the integer constant `-1` is converted to the type `unsigned short` and if your compiler supports the 2's complement representation of integers the converted value represents the positive value USHRT_MAX.

Answer (score 0):

Because you have defined `y` as `unsigned short`. Because `-1` is absolutely a signed int so the compiler will not store it into y as `-1` instead it will be stored as `65535` which is the overflow result of `-1`. i.e. unsigned short range `65536` `-` `1`.

Comment: The `unsigned short` range is not set in stone, but it's never `65536 - 1`. `[0, 65536)` (`[0, 65535]`) is possible.though

Comment: The `unsigned short` range is `[0, 65,535]` which means `65536` possibilities. so because -1 is stored in Two's complement in the memory it's stored like that `0b11111111` which will be interpreted as `65,535` when dealing with it as unsigned value.

Comment: The `unsigned short` range _may_ be `[0,65535]`. It's _at least_ 16 bits but it can be wider. What I mainly opposed was "_unsigned short range `65536` `-` `1`_" which is a very strange way of describing ranges.