# Operator "<<= " : What does it it mean?

Tags: c, operators

I need help solving this problem in my mind, so if anyone had a similar problem it would help me.

Here's my code:

```
char c=0xAB;
printf("01:%x\n", c<<2);
printf("02:%x\n", c<<=2);
printf("03:%x\n", c<<=2);
```

Why the program prints:

```
01:fffffeac
02:ffffffac
03:ffffffb0
```

What I expected to print, that is, what I got on paper is:

```
01:fffffeac
02:fffffeac
03:fffffab0
```

I obviously realized I didn't know what the operator `<<=` was doing, I thought `c = c << 2`.

If anyone can clarify this, I would be grateful.

Comment: I reviewed it, but it didn’t help me :(

Comment: How do we get for the second printf: ffffffac ? So how is the first print different from the second?

Comment: I believe it has to do with the first one being promoted to `int` and printed as an `int`, and the 2nd one promoted to `int` (for the shift) then back to `char` (to be stored in `c`) then back to `int` again to be printed.

Comment: Yes it is most likely, now I have noticed it too

Comment: Technically you have *undefined behavior* in your code: The format specifier `%x` is for **unsigned** integers, while the result of your operations will be a signed integer. Such mismatch between format specifier and argument type is UB.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude That's debatable.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4664100/does-printfx-1-invoke-undefined-behavior

Comment: `char c; ... c<<=2` is very fishy code and likely broken. To begin with, drop `char` and use `uint8_t`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're correct in thinking that

```
c <<= 2
```

is equivalent to

```
c = c << 2
```

***But*** you have to remember that `c` is a *single byte* (on almost all systems), it can only contain eight bits, while a value like `0xeac` requires 12 bits.

When the value `0xeac` is assigned back to `c` then the value will be *truncated* and the top bits will simply be ignored, leaving you with `0xac` (which when promoted to an `int` becomes `0xffffffac`).

Comment: The left shifts of negative values are not defined by the C standard, and the assignments of out-of-range values to signed `char` are implementation-defined. `char` is a byte in C by definition; it is eight bits on almost all systems.

Answer (score 0):

`<<=` means shift and assign. It's the *compound assignment* version of `c = c << 2;`.

There's several problems here:

- `char c=0xAB;` is not guaranteed to give a positive result, since `char` could be an 8 bit signed type. See [Is char signed or unsigned by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2054939/is-char-signed-or-unsigned-by-default). In which case `0xAB` will get translated to a negative number in an implementation-defined way. Avoid this bug by always using `uint8_t` when dealing with raw binary bytes.
- `c<<2` is subject to [Implicit type promotion rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46073295/implicit-type-promotion-rules) - specifically `c` will get promoted to a signed `int`. If the previous issue occured where your `char` got a negative value, `c` now holds a negative `int`.
- Left-shifting negative values in C invokes undefined behavior - it is always a bug. Shifting signed operands in general is almost never correct.
- `%x` isn't a suitable format specifier to print the `int` you ended up with, nor is it suitable for `char`.

As for how to fix the code, it depends on what you wish to achieve. It's recommended to cast to `uint32` before shifting.