# What is the need of hh and h format specifiers?

Tags: c, scanf, format-specifiers

In the code below **`mac_str` is char pointer** and **`mac`** is a **`uint8_t` array**:

```
 sscanf(mac_str,"%x:%x:%x:%x:%x:%x",&mac[0],&mac[1],&mac[2],&mac[3],&mac[4],&mac[5]);
```

When I try the above code it gives me a warning:

```
warning: format ‘%x’ expects argument of type ‘unsigned int *’, but argument 8 has type ‘uint8_t *’ [-Wformat]
```

but I saw in some code they specified

```
sscanf(str,"%hhx:%hhx:%hhx:%hhx:%hhx:%hhx",&mac[0],&mac[1],&mac[2],&mac[3],&mac[4],&mac[5]);
```

which doesn't give any warning but both are working the same.

What's the need of using **`hhx`** instead of just **`x`**?

Comment: `hh` stands for, as a historical guess, for _half of a half_. That is, a byte.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4586962/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-h-and-hh-modifiers-for-printf

Comment: use `sscanf("%" SCNx8 , &x);` <inttypes.h>

Comment: @Joseph I didnt say it was a duplicate. However there is some information in that other topic that OP might find interesting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`&mac[0]` is a pointer to an `unsigned char`.<sup>1</sup> `%hhx` means the corresponding arguments points to an `unsigned char`. Use square pegs for square holes: the conversion specifiers in the format string must match the argument types.

---

<sup>1</sup> Actually, `&mac[0]` is a pointer to a `uint8_t`, and `%hhx` is still wrong for `uint8_t`. It “works” in many implementations because `uint8_t` is the same as `unsigned char` in many implementations. But the proper format is `"%" SCNx8`, as in:

```
#include <inttypes.h>
…
scanf(mac_str, "%" SCNx8 "… rest of format string", &mac[0], … rest of arguments);
```

Comment: Strictly speaking, I believe that if `uint8_t` exists it must be the same as `unsigned char`.

Comment: @StephenCanon: I expect so, but I am having difficulty interpreting C 2011 7.20.1 1: “When typedef names differing only in the absence or presence of the initial **u** are defined,…”. I am wondering whether an implementation could provide `uint8_t` but not provide `int8_t`, due to stubbornness, and then not be compelled by 7.20.1 1 to make `uint8_t` be an `unsigned char` or `char`. Then the implementation could provide another integer type, say `__byte`, that is an unsigned 8-bit integer but is different from `char` or `unsigned char`. So aliasing rules would apply, et cetera.

Answer (score 6):

`hh` is a *length modifier* that specifies the destination type of the argument. The default for conversion format specifier `x` is `unsigned int*`. With `hh`, it becomes `unsigned char*` or `signed char*`.

Refer to the table [`herein`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fscanf) for more details.

Comment: C11 §7.21.6.2 says "**x** .... corresponding argument shall be a pointer to unsigned integer."  I see nothing about `signed int*`.

Answer (score 3):

`hhx` converts input to unsigned char, while `x` converts to unsigned int. And since `uint8_t` is typedef to `unsigned char`, `hhx` fixes warning.