# How to hash NSString with SHA1 in Swift?

Tags: swift, sha1

In objective-c it looks like this:

```
#include <sys/xattr.h>

@implementation NSString (reverse)

-(NSString*)sha1
{
    NSData *data = [self dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    uint8_t digest[CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH];
    CC_SHA1(data.bytes, (int)data.length, digest);
    NSMutableString *output = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH * 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++)
        [output appendFormat:@"%02x", digest[i]];
    return output;
}

@end
```

I need something like this with Swift, is it possible?

Please, show work example.

Answer (score 197, accepted):

Your Objective-C code (using a `NSString` category) can be directly translated to Swift
(using a `String` extension).

First you have to create a "bridging header" and add

```
#import <CommonCrypto/CommonCrypto.h>
```

Then:

```
extension String {
    func sha1() -> String {
        let data = self.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
        var digest = [UInt8](count:Int(CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH), repeatedValue: 0)
        CC_SHA1(data.bytes, CC_LONG(data.length), &digest)
        let output = NSMutableString(capacity: Int(CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH))
        for byte in digest {
            output.appendFormat("%02x", byte)
        }
        return output as String
    }
}

println("Hello World".sha1())
```

This can be written slightly shorter and Swifter as

```
extension String {
    func sha1() -> String {
        let data = self.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
        var digest = [UInt8](count:Int(CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH), repeatedValue: 0)
        CC_SHA1(data.bytes, CC_LONG(data.length), &digest)
        let hexBytes = map(digest) { String(format: "%02hhx", $0) }
        return "".join(hexBytes)
    }
}
```

**Update for Swift 2:**

```
extension String {
    func sha1() -> String {
        let data = self.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
        var digest = [UInt8](count:Int(CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH), repeatedValue: 0)
        CC_SHA1(data.bytes, CC_LONG(data.length), &digest)
        let hexBytes = digest.map { String(format: "%02hhx", $0) }
        return hexBytes.joinWithSeparator("")
    }
}
```

To return a Base-64 encoded string instead of a hex encoded string,
just replace

```
        let hexBytes = digest.map { String(format: "%02hhx", $0) }
        return hexBytes.joinWithSeparator("")
```

with

```
        return NSData(bytes: digest, length: digest.count).base64EncodedStringWithOptions([])
```

**Update for Swift 3:**

```
extension String {
    func sha1() -> String {
        let data = self.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!
        var digest = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count:Int(CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH))
        data.withUnsafeBytes { 
            _ = CC_SHA1($0, CC_LONG(data.count), &digest)
        }
        let hexBytes = digest.map { String(format: "%02hhx", $0) }
        return hexBytes.joined()
    }
}
```

To return a Base-64 encoded string instead of a hex encoded string,
just replace

```
        let hexBytes = digest.map { String(format: "%02hhx", $0) }
        return hexBytes.joined()
```

by

```
        return Data(bytes: digest).base64EncodedString()
```

**Update for Swift 4:**

The bridging header file is no longer needed, one can `import CommonCrypto` instead:

```
import CommonCrypto

extension String {
    func sha1() -> String {
        let data = Data(self.utf8)
        var digest = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count:Int(CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH))
        data.withUnsafeBytes { 
            _ = CC_SHA1($0, CC_LONG(data.count), &digest)
        }
        let hexBytes = digest.map { String(format: "%02hhx", $0) }
        return hexBytes.joined()
    }
}
```

**Update for Swift 5:**

The `Data.withUnsafeBytes()` method now calls the closure with an `UnsafeRawBufferPointer` to, and `baseAddress` is used to pass the initial address to the C function:

```
import CommonCrypto

extension String {
    func sha1() -> String {
        let data = Data(self.utf8)
        var digest = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count:Int(CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH))
        data.withUnsafeBytes { 
            _ = CC_SHA1($0.baseAddress, CC_LONG(data.count), &digest)
        }
        let hexBytes = digest.map { String(format: "%02hhx", $0) }
        return hexBytes.joined()
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible without using obj-c bridging header? I looking for clean Swift solution.

Comment: @MihaelIsaev: What do you mean by a "clean Swift solution"? Do you want to *re-implement* the algorithms in Swift? I would not recommend it because CommonCrypto is a working established solution. But you might have a look at https://github.com/krzyzanowskim/CryptoSwift.

Comment: Yeah, I want some library that I can use without obj-c bridging. Unfortunately https://github.com/krzyzanowskim/CryptoSwift it is using obj-c bridging too :(

Comment: @MihaelIsaev CryptoSwift is not using bridging.

Comment: As of swift 1.2 NSString is not implicitly bridged to a Swift String so you might need to add a cast :)

Comment: @DanielGalasko: You are completely right, thanks for letting me know! I have updated the code for Swift 1.2 (and added another possible solution).

Comment: Why the difference in %02x and %02hhx ?

Comment: @MobileBloke: Did you add `#import <CommonCrypto/CommonCrypto.h>` to the bridging header file, as mentioned above?

Comment: Update for Swift 3 doesn't work with Xcode 8 beta 5.

Comment: @MattLong: What error do you get? That code compiles and runs in my Xcode 8 beta 5.

Comment: @MartinR My bad. Was unintentionally trying to add it as an extension on Data rather than String. Derp! Move along. Nothing to see here.

Comment: With the latest Swift version, you can now just add `import CommonCrypto` at the top of your Swift file. It's no longer necessary to manually create a module map or bridging header as it's now part of the SDK.

Comment: @BenBaron: You are right (and that works already in Swift 4), thanks.

Comment: By chance I ended up finding this out the other day because a framework I wanted to use included a CommonCrypto module map and wouldn't compile due to redefining the module.

Comment: @user965972 "`hhx` converts input to `unsigned char`, while `x` converts to `unsigned int`." See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21782244

Answer (score 20):

With `CryptoKit` added in iOS13, we now have native Swift API:

```swift
import Foundation
import CryptoKit

// CryptoKit.Digest utils
extension Digest {
    var bytes: [UInt8] { Array(makeIterator()) }
    var data: Data { Data(bytes) }

    var hexStr: String {
        bytes.map { String(format: "%02X", $0) }.joined()
    }
}

func example() {
    guard let data = "hello world".data(using: .utf8) else { return }
    let digest = Insecure.SHA1.hash(data: data)
    print(digest.data) // 20 bytes
    print(digest.hexStr) // 2AAE6C35C94FCFB415DBE95F408B9CE91EE846ED
}
```

Comment: Ok, so let's wait a couple of years before using it (because of iSO13+) :)

Comment: @imike sure, 

Comment: on `hexStr` you don't need to use `bytes.map`, `self.map` should work too (thanks to the underlying iterator)

Comment: Works fine on the server :)

Answer (score 7):

A version for Swift 5 that uses CryptoKit on iOS 13 and falls back to CommonCrypto otherwise:

```swift
import CommonCrypto
import CryptoKit
import Foundation

private func hexString(_ iterator: Array<UInt8>.Iterator) -> String {
    return iterator.map { String(format: "%02x", $0) }.joined()
}

extension Data {

    public var sha1: String {
        if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
            return hexString(Insecure.SHA1.hash(data: self).makeIterator())
        } else {
            var digest = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: Int(CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH))
            self.withUnsafeBytes { bytes in
                _ = CC_SHA1(bytes.baseAddress, CC_LONG(self.count), &digest)
            }
            return hexString(digest.makeIterator())
        }
    }

}
```

Usage:

```
let string = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"
let hexDigest = string.data(using: .ascii)!.sha1
assert(hexDigest == "2fd4e1c67a2d28fced849ee1bb76e7391b93eb12")
```

Also available via Swift package manager:
https://github.com/ralfebert/TinyHashes

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it's possible, copy this class into your project.
https://github.com/idrougge/sha1-swift

And it will be easy like:

```
 SHA1.hexString(from: "myPhrase" )!
```

**Tested for swift 3 and swift 4.**

Comment: Could you please provide more code? What I should import to call just `SHA1.hexString(from: "myPhrase" )!`?

Comment: Download this code and paste it to your project.
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/idrougge/sha1-swift/master/SHA1.swift
That is enough to use it @MihaelIsaev

Answer (score 4):

To get the result as `NSData`, provided that you included `<CommonCrypto/CommonCrypto.h>` in your bridging header:

```
extension NSData {

    func sha1() -> NSData? {
        let len = Int(CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH)
        let digest = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>.alloc(len)
        CC_SHA1(bytes, CC_LONG(length), digest)
        return NSData(bytesNoCopy: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>(digest), length: len)
    }
}
```

Also uses proper pointer allocation. Invoke it like this:

```
myString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)?.sha1()
```

If you need a hex representation of `NSData` have a look at my other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520615/how-to-convert-an-nsdata-into-an-nsstring-hex-string/7520655#7520655).

Comment: There seems to be a memory leak. You have to dealloc `digest`, or use `NSData(bytesNoCopy: ..)`.

Comment: With the latest Swift version, you can now just add import CommonCrypto at the top of your Swift file. It's no longer necessary to manually create a module map or bridging header as it's now part of the SDK.

Answer (score 1):

We can extract logic for encrypting string using sha1 for three steps:

1. Convert string to Data object
2. Encrypt data using SHA1 function to Data
3. Convert data object to hex string

IMHO it's much more readable and this version doesn't require NSData.

```
    extension String {

        var sha1: String {
            guard let data = data(using: .utf8, allowLossyConversion: false) else {
                // Here you can just return empty string or execute fatalError with some description that this specific string can not be converted to data
            }
            return data.digestSHA1.hexString
        }

    }

    fileprivate extension Data {

        var digestSHA1: Data {
            var bytes: [UInt8] = Array(repeating: 0, count: Int(CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH))

            withUnsafeBytes {
                _ = CC_SHA1($0, CC_LONG(count), &bytes)
            }

            return Data(bytes: bytes)
        }

        var hexString: String {
            return map { String(format: "%02x", UInt8($0)) }.joined()
        }

    }
```

Comment: Note that a conversion to UTF-8 *cannot* fail.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible: *make that objective-c code accessible from swift*

See [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH10-XID_76).

I would avoid rewriting it in swift if you won't get any benefit (such as using swift-specific features).

Also, in a project I am working on I used some objective-c code similar to yours to handle hashes. At beginning I started writing it in swift, then I realized that it was just easier and better to reuse old good obj-c.

Comment: It's not only about iOS, e.g. I also use Swift for server-side code on Linux and there are no way to use Obj-C bridging. Btw at that time there are a lot of native Swift's solutions for hashing already :)

Answer (score 0):

For one-liner guy, no need to use the creepy swift extension

Swift 5.7.3

```
import CryptoKit

func mysha1(_ str:String) -> String {

  return Insecure.SHA1.hash(data: str.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!).map
  { String(format: "%02x", $0) }.joined()

}
```