# Generate a HMAC swift sdk8.3 using CCHmac()

Tags: ios, swift

Before SDK8.3 I was generating my hmac this way. Now I get an error on the CCHmac() function. Since I'm a beginner I can't figure out how to fix it. Thanks in advance for your help!

> xcode warning: cannot involke 'CCHmac' with an argument list of type (UInt32, [CChar]?, UInt, [CChar]?, UInt, inout[(CUnsignedChar)]

```
func generateHMAC(key: String, data: String) -> String {

    let cKey = key.cStringUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    let cData = data.cStringUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)

    var result = [CUnsignedChar](count: Int(CC_SHA512_DIGEST_LENGTH), repeatedValue: 0)
    CCHmac(CCHmacAlgorithm(kCCHmacAlgSHA512), cKey, strlen(cKey!), cData, strlen(cData!), &result)


    let hash = NSMutableString()
    for var i = 0; i < result.count; i++ {
        hash.appendFormat("%02hhx", result[i])
    }

    return hash as String
}
```

Comment: Similar (perhaps useful) method here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25762128/1187415.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that `strlen` returns a `UInt`, while `CCHmac`’s length arguments are `Int`s.

While you could do some coercion, you may as well just use the `count` property of the two arrays rather than calling `strlen`.

```
func generateHMAC(key: String, data: String) -> String {

    var result: [CUnsignedChar]
    if let cKey = key.cStringUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding),
           cData = data.cStringUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    {
        let algo  = CCHmacAlgorithm(kCCHmacAlgSHA512)
        result = Array(count: Int(CC_SHA512_DIGEST_LENGTH), repeatedValue: 0)

        CCHmac(algo, cKey, cKey.count-1, cData, cData.count-1, &result)
    }
    else {
        // as @MartinR points out, this is in theory impossible 
        // but personally, I prefer doing this to using `!`
        fatalError("Nil returned when processing input strings as UTF8")
    }

    let hash = NSMutableString()
    for val in result {
        hash.appendFormat("%02hhx", val)
    }

    return hash as String
}
```

Comment: You are again to fast :) – But note that with `.count` you'll include the terminating zero of the string, this gives a different result compared to the original code with `strlen()`. But actually I would convert the string to `NSData` instead, compare http://stackoverflow.com/a/25762128/1187415 for a similar method. – And the conversion to UTF-8 *cannot* fail.

Comment: And again, I make a basic error by trying to be too fast :o  Thanks, fixed.

Comment: Still, UTF-8 can represent all Unicode strings, so I do not think that the conversion can fail at all.

Comment: Odd then that they made it optional after auditing (it would originally have been implicitly unwrapped pre-audit?  I don’t have the old headers to hand)

Comment: Oh ignore me I’m being stupid, there are other encodings that might fail