# Cannot invoke 'CCHmac' with an argument list of type '(UInt32, UnsafePointer<Int8>, UInt, [CChar], Int, UnsafeMutablePointer<CUnsignedChar>)

Tags: ios, swift

I updated xCode and/or swift 1.0 to 1.2 and got lots of errors,

I knew some of the methods are updated/Changed in Swift 1.2 hence I started updating my whole project to swift 1.2. I am stuck on this line:

```
CCHmac(CCHmacAlgorithm(kCCHmacAlgSHA1), cKey, strlen(cKey), str!, strLen, result)
```

It's throwing error `Cannot invoke 'CCHmac' with an argument list of type '(UInt32, UnsafePointer<Int8>, UInt, [CChar], Int, UnsafeMutablePointer<CUnsignedChar>)'`

here is my code

```
.
.
.
 let str = cred.cStringUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        let strLen:Int = Int(cred.lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding))
        let digestLen = Int(CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH)
        let result = UnsafeMutablePointer<CUnsignedChar>.alloc(digestLen)
        let objcKey = key as NSString
        let keyStr = Key.cStringUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        let keyLen:Int = Int(Key.lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding))

        var st:NSString = dataFromHexadecimalString(Key)!
        let cKey = st.cStringUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)


        CCHmac(CCHmacAlgorithm(kCCHmacAlgSHA1), cKey, strlen(cKey), str!, strLen, result)
.
.
.
```

Note: I changed `keyLen` and `strLen` from `Uint to Int` but still its throwing the same error.

Comment: Compare http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29799361/generate-a-hmac-swift-sdk8-3-using-cchmac.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it just cast the strlen(cKey) to int like `Int(strlen(cKey))`

whole line look like is

```
CCHmac(CCHmacAlgorithm(kCCHmacAlgSHA1), cKey, Int(strlen(cKey)), str!, strLen, result)
```