# Generating SHA256 in iOS

Tags: ios, windows-phone, sha256, hmac

I tried to generate SHA256 in iOS using [Arcane](https://cocoapods.org/pods/Arcane) library with following data:

String: `Amount=50&BillerID=59&ChannelID=2&Context=34|check|test&ReturnURL=https://uat.myfatoora.com/ReceiptPOC.aspx&TxnRefNum=000000000020003&UserName=DCS`

Key: `71DD0F73AFFBB47825FF9864DDE95F3B`

Result was `409dc622b3bef5c9fc46e45c3210111fcb4536d3a55833316fe0dc8154b3ea34`

which I thought to be correct. However, the Windows counterpart is generating SHA256 using following code:

```
Windows Phone Source Code:

public static string HmacSha256(string secretKey, string value)
    {
        var msg = CryptographicBuffer.ConvertStringToBinary(value, BinaryStringEncoding.Utf8);
        byte[] convertedHash = new byte[secretKey.Length / 2];

        for (int i = 0; i < secretKey.Length / 2; i++)
        {
            convertedHash[i] = (byte)Int32.Parse(secretKey.Substring(i * 2, 2), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
        }

        // Create HMAC.
        var objMacProv = MacAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm(MacAlgorithmNames.HmacSha256);
        CryptographicHash hash = objMacProv.CreateHash(convertedHash.AsBuffer());

        hash.Append(msg);
        return CryptographicBuffer.EncodeToHexString(hash.GetValueAndReset());

    }
```

and the result is: `94a20ca39c8487c7763823ec9c918d9e38ae83cb741439f6d129bcdef9edba73` which is different from what I got. Can somebody help me with this and let me know what the above code is doing and how can I replicate it in iOS.

**Edit:**

```
 iOS Source code

 let key = self.md5(string: "71DD0F73AFFBB47825FF9864DDE95F3B")

    let hash = HMAC.SHA256(str, key: key)
```

Comment: You didn't show any code about iOS side. Also SHA256 and HMAC-SHA256 are different things.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen: I've added the iOS source; it's using Arcane library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key here is you need to convert your secret, which is a hex string, into NSData. In other words, `NSData` byte stream would "look" like the secret.

This should do what you want:

```
    // Hex string to NSData conversion from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7317860/converting-hex-nsstring-to-nsdata
    NSString *secret = @"71DD0F73AFFBB47825FF9864DDE95F3B";
    NSData *dataIn = [@"Amount=50&BillerID=59&ChannelID=2&Context=34|check|test&ReturnURL=https://uat.myfatoora.com/ReceiptPOC.aspx&TxnRefNum=000000000020003&UserName=DCS" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSMutableData *macOut = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH];

    secret = [secret stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
    NSMutableData *secretData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
    unsigned char whole_byte;
    char byte_chars[3] = {'\0','\0','\0'};
    int i;
    for (i=0; i < [secret length]/2; i++) {
        byte_chars[0] = [secret characterAtIndex:i*2];
        byte_chars[1] = [secret characterAtIndex:i*2+1];
        whole_byte = strtol(byte_chars, NULL, 16);
        [secretData appendBytes:&whole_byte length:1];
    }

    CCHmac(kCCHmacAlgSHA256, secretData.bytes, secretData.length, dataIn.bytes, dataIn.length, macOut.mutableBytes);

    NSMutableString *stringOut = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:macOut.length];
    const unsigned char *macOutBytes = macOut.bytes;

    for (NSInteger i=0; i<macOut.length; ++i) {
        [stringOut appendFormat:@"%02x", macOutBytes[i]];
    }

    NSLog(@"dataIn: %@", dataIn);
    NSLog(@"macOut: %@", macOut);
    NSLog(@"stringOut: %@", stringOut);
```

Output:

2016-09-27 20:18:54.181 JKS[27562:5321334] dataIn: <416d6f75 6e743d35 30264269 6c6c6572 49443d35 39264368 616e6e65 6c49443d 3226436f 6e746578 743d3334 7c636865 636b7c74 65737426 52657475 726e5552 4c3d6874 7470733a 2f2f7561 742e6d79 6661746f 6f72612e 636f6d2f 52656365 69707450 4f432e61 73707826 54786e52 65664e75 6d3d3030 30303030 30303030 32303030 33265573 65724e61 6d653d44 4353>

2016-09-27 20:18:54.181 JKS[27562:5321334] macOut: <94a20ca3 9c8487c7 763823ec 9c918d9e 38ae83cb 741439f6 d129bcde f9edba73>

2016-09-27 20:18:54.181 JKS[27562:5321334] stringOut: 94a20ca39c8487c7763823ec9c918d9e38ae83cb741439f6d129bcdef9edba73

> Updated with Swift (code should be cleaned up)

```
// http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29799361/generate-a-hmac-swift-sdk8-3-using-cchmac
func generateHMAC(key: String, data: String) -> String {
    let keyData = key.dataFromHexadecimalString()! as NSData
    let dataIn = data.data(using: .utf8)! as NSData
    var result: [CUnsignedChar]
    result = Array(repeating: 0, count: Int(CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH))
    CCHmac(CCHmacAlgorithm(kCCHmacAlgSHA256), keyData.bytes, keyData.length, dataIn.bytes, dataIn.length, &result)

    let hash = NSMutableString()
    for val in result {
        hash.appendFormat("%02hhx", val)
    }

    return hash as String
}
```

You can use this extension to convert the hex string to `Data`

```
// Modified slightly http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26501276/converting-hex-string-to-nsdata-in-swift
extension String {

    func dataFromHexadecimalString() -> Data? {
        var data = Data(capacity: characters.count / 2)

        let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "[0-9a-f]{1,2}", options: .caseInsensitive)
        regex.enumerateMatches(in: self, options: [], range: NSMakeRange(0, characters.count)) { match, flags, stop in
            let byteString = (self as NSString).substring(with: match!.range)
            var num = UInt8(byteString, radix: 16)
            data.append(&num!, count: 1)
        }

        return data
    }
}
```

And to use do something like:

```
    let secret = "71DD0F73AFFBB47825FF9864DDE95F3B"
    let value = "Amount=50&BillerID=59&ChannelID=2&Context=34|check|test&ReturnURL=https://uat.myfatoora.com/ReceiptPOC.aspx&TxnRefNum=000000000020003&UserName=DCS"

    print("\(generateHMAC(key: secret, data: value))")
```

Your output should be 94a20ca39c8487c7763823ec9c918d9e38ae83cb741439f6d129bcdef9edba73

You will need `#import <CommonCrypto/CommonCrypto.h>` in your bridging header.

Comment: Oh, you'll need #import <CommonCrypto/CommonHMAC.h>

Comment: Ugh, sorry it's Obj-C, but you should be able to do the same with Swift, `CCHmac` is available there. Here is a link to some reference on doing that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29799361/generate-a-hmac-swift-sdk8-3-using-cchmac

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. Could you please tell me   what is data.data in ` let dataIn = data.data(using: .utf8)! as NSData`  because it is giving me error. I assume you are converting String to NSData.

Comment: Many thanks to you @MobileBen. This is what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

The Windows code takes the string, interprets it as a hexadecimal number, and converts two characters a time into one byte.

Your Mac code most like takes the string *as it is*. Since the key starts with "71", your windows code takes that as a single byte with value 0x71 = 129, your Mac code takes it as two bytes with values '7' = 55 and '1' = 49.

All you need to do is convert the bytes on the Mac exactly as you do it on Windows. You might have to do the unthinkable and look at the source code of the Mac library to see how it does the actual hash calculation.

Comment: I tried to do something like this 

`  for i in 0...secretKey.length / 2 {
                let range = NSMakeRange(i*2, 2)
                if range.location < 32 {
                convertedHash.appendData(secretKey.substringWithRange(range).dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
                }
            }`

 but it didn't help. Can you please post some code.

Answer (score 0):

```html
#import <CommonCrypto/CommonHMAC.h>

+ (NSString *)hmacSHA256EncryptString{


    NSString * parameterSecret = @"input secret key";
    NSString *plainString = @"input encrypt content string";
    const char *secretKey  = [parameterSecret cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    const char *plainData = [plainString cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    unsigned char cHMAC[CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH];
    CCHmac(kCCHmacAlgSHA256, secretKey, strlen(secretKey), plainData, strlen(plainData), cHMAC);
    NSData *HMACData = [NSData dataWithBytes:cHMAC length:sizeof(cHMAC)];
    const unsigned char *bufferChar = (const unsigned char *)[HMACData bytes];
    NSMutableString *hmacString = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:HMACData.length * 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < HMACData.length; ++i){
        [hmacString appendFormat:@"%02x", bufferChar[i]];
    }
    return hmacString;
    
}
```