# Hash function with Glibc

Tags: swift, linux, glibc

I have been trying to encrypt strings in Swift, however I want it to work under linux. Answers like the below code (taken from [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25388747/sha256-in-swift) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39921117/sha-256-encryption-syntax-error-in-swift-3-0?noredirect=1&lq=1) does not work, as they depend either on iOS or OSx libraries:

```
func sha256(data : Data) -> Data {
    var hash = [UInt8](repeating: 0,  count: Int(CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH))
    data.withUnsafeBytes {
        _ = CC_SHA256($0, CC_LONG(data.count), &hash)
    }
    return Data(bytes: hash)
}
```

- How can that be done using Glibc in linux?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a crypt library in glibc, [see manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/crypt.3.html).
You need to include: `#include <crypt.h>`.

The function you have to use is:

```
char *crypt(const char *key, const char *salt);
```

According to that manpage the SHA-256 algorithm is integrated since glibc 2.7 and is selected via the `salt` argument:

> ```
> The glibc2 version of this function supports additional encryption
> algorithms.
>
> If salt is a character string starting with the characters "$id$"
> followed by a string terminated by "$":
>
>        $id$salt$encrypted
>
> then instead of using the DES machine, id identifies the encryption
> method used and this then determines how the rest of the password
> string is interpreted.  The following values of id are supported:
>
>        ID  | Method
>        ─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
>        1   | MD5
>        2a  | Blowfish (not in mainline glibc; added in some
>            | Linux distributions)
>        5   | SHA-256 (since glibc 2.7)
>        6   | SHA-512 (since glibc 2.7)
>
> So $5$salt$encrypted is an SHA-256 encoded password and
> $6$salt$encrypted is an SHA-512 encoded one.
>
> "salt" stands for the up to 16 characters following "$id$" in the
> salt.  The encrypted part of the password string is the actual
> computed password.  The size of this string is fixed:
>
> MD5     | 22 characters
> SHA-256 | 43 characters
> SHA-512 | 86 characters
>
> The characters in "salt" and "encrypted" are drawn from the set
> [a-zA-Z0-9./].  In the MD5 and SHA implementations the entire key is
> significant (instead of only the first 8 bytes in DES).
> ```

On [this official GNU page](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/crypt.html) and [this wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crypt_(C)) are explanations and examples:

Example `salt` argument for SHA-256:
`$5$9ks3nNEqv31FX.F$gdEoLFsCRsn/WRN3wxUnzfeZLoooVlzeF4WjLomTRFD`