# Swift 3: Encode String to UTF-16LE

Tags: swift, utf-8, utf-16le

I need to encode a string to UTF-16LE (and convert to sha1 later), but I'm having some problems. This is what I had tried:

```
let utf16array = Array("password".utf16)
print(utf16array)
// [112, 97, 115, 115, 119, 111, 114, 100]
```

But this is what I was expecting:

```
// [112, 0, 97, 0, 115, 0, 115, 0, 119, 0, 111, 0, 114, 0, 100, 0]
```

Same thing using utf8array:

```
let utf8array = "password".utf8.map({ $0 as UInt8 })
// [112, 97, 115, 115, 119, 111, 114, 100]
```

So, this is what I did to "fix" it:

```
var bytesArray:[UInt16] = []
for byte in utf16array {
    bytesArray.append(byte)
    bytesArray.append(0)
}
print(bytesArray)
// [112, 0, 97, 0, 115, 0, 115, 0, 119, 0, 111, 0, 114, 0, 100, 0]
```

But I'm sure this is not the right way. Any suggestions?

Comment: The contents of the UTF-16 array are all 16-bit integers, so those 0 bytes that you're expecting are already included in each value. You've changed the data by inserting those extra zeroes (which are also 16 bits apiece).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get a representation as UTF-16LE data with

```
let password = "password€"
let data = password.data(using: .utf16LittleEndian)!
print(data as NSData)
// <70006100 73007300 77006f00 72006400 ac20>
```

That would already be sufficient to compute the SHA1 digest (code
from [How to crypt string to sha1 with Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25761344/how-to-crypt-string-to-sha1-with-swift/25762128#25762128)):

```
var digest = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count:Int(CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH))
data.withUnsafeBytes { 
    _ = CC_SHA1($0, CC_LONG(data.count), &digest)
}
let hexEncodedDigest = digest.map { String(format: "%02hhx", $0) }.joined()
print(hexEncodedDigest)
// 177f0d080dfe533e102dd67d6321204813cf1b0c
```

But if you need it as a byte array then

```
let bytesArray = data.map { $0 }
print(bytesArray)
// [112, 0, 97, 0, 115, 0, 115, 0, 119, 0, 111, 0, 114, 0, 100, 0, 172, 32]
```

would work.

(I have appended a non-ASCII characters for demonstration,
`€ = U+20AC` becomes `172, 32`.)

---

If you are curious how to convert the `[UInt16]` array to an
`[UInt8]` array, this is how you could do it with some pointer juggling
(and just a single copy):

```
let utf16array = Array("password€".utf16)
print(utf16array)
// [112, 97, 115, 115, 119, 111, 114, 100, 8364]

let bytes = Array(utf16array.withUnsafeBufferPointer {
    $0.baseAddress!.withMemoryRebound(to: UInt8.self, capacity: 2 * utf16array.count) {
        UnsafeBufferPointer(start: $0, count: 2 * utf16array.count)
    }
})
print(bytes)
// [112, 0, 97, 0, 115, 0, 115, 0, 119, 0, 111, 0, 114, 0, 100, 0, 172, 32]
```

Comment: You rock! This is exactly what I was looking for. Worked like a charm. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Using the [`String` to `Data` method `data(using:)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40116666/4573247) is the fit for purpose solution here.

But for the fun of it, an alternative making use of the `String`:s UTF-16 encoding approach (`utf16` property of `String`) of the OP. Using the `init(truncatingBitPattern: UInt16)` initializer of `UInt8`, in combination with `zip` followed by a `flatMap`, the latter flattening the zipped tuples into an array:

```
let pw = "password€"

let bytes = zip(pw.utf16.map{ UInt8(truncatingBitPattern: $0) },
                pw.utf16.map{ UInt8(truncatingBitPattern: $0 >> 8) })
            .flatMap{ [$0, $1] }

print(bytes)
// [112, 0, 97, 0, 115, 0, 115, 0, 119, 0, 111, 0, 114, 0, 100, 0, 172, 32]
```

Answer (score 0):

What about using the [`cString`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsstring/1408489-cstring) accessor?

```
var bytes = str.cStringUsingEncoding(NSUTF16LittleEndianStringEncoding)
```