# Swift 5.0: 'withUnsafeBytes' is deprecated: use `withUnsafeBytes<R>(...)

Tags: swift, deprecated, unsafe-pointers

I previously used this code in Swift 4.2 to generate an id:

```
public static func generateId() throws -> UInt32 {
    let data: Data = try random(bytes: 4)
    let value: UInt32 = data.withUnsafeBytes { $0.pointee } // deprecated warning!
    return value // + some other stuff 
}
```

`withUnsafeBytes` is deprecated on Swift 5.0. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 79, accepted):

In Swift 5 the `withUnsafeBytes()` method of `Data` calls the closure with an (untyped) `UnsafeRawBufferPointer`, and you can [`load()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/unsaferawbufferpointer/2632297-load) the value from the raw memory:

```
let value = data.withUnsafeBytes { $0.load(as: UInt32.self) }
```

(compare [How to use Data.withUnsafeBytes in a well-defined manner?](https://forums.swift.org/t/how-to-use-data-withunsafebytes-in-a-well-defined-manner/12811) in the Swift forum). Note that this requires that the memory is *aligned* on a 4-byte boundary. For alternatives see [round trip Swift number types to/from Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38023838/round-trip-swift-number-types-to-from-data).

Note also that as of Swift 4.2 you can create a random 32-bit integer simply using the new [`Random` API](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0202-random-unification.md):

```
let randomId = UInt32.random(in: .min ... .max)
```

Comment: Can you tell me how go with this one: data.withUnsafeBytes {
            CC_SHA256($0, CC_LONG(data.count), &buffer)
        } ??

Comment: @mientus: Have a look at the Swift 5 update in https://stackoverflow.com/a/25762128/1187415.

Comment: @MartinR when there is nil/unreal  then i got `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x20)` how can we handle it ?

Answer (score 26):

On Xcode 10.2, Swift 5, using `$0.load(as:)` didn't work for me, both when reading from the pointer or writing to it.

Instead, using `$0.baseAddress?.assumingMemoryBound(to:)` seems to work well.

Example reading from the pointer buffer (code is unrelated to the question):

```swift
var reachability: SCNetworkReachability?
data.withUnsafeBytes { ptr in
    guard let bytes = ptr.baseAddress?.assumingMemoryBound(to: Int8.self) else {
        return
    }
    reachability = SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithName(nil, bytes)
}
```

Example writing to the buffer pointer (code is unrelated to the question):

```swift
try outputData.withUnsafeMutableBytes { (outputBytes: UnsafeMutableRawBufferPointer) in
    let status = CCKeyDerivationPBKDF(CCPBKDFAlgorithm(kCCPBKDF2),
                                      passphrase,
                                      passphrase.utf8.count,
                                      salt,
                                      salt.utf8.count,
                                      CCPseudoRandomAlgorithm(kCCPRFHmacAlgSHA1),
                                      rounds,
                                      outputBytes.baseAddress?.assumingMemoryBound(to: UInt8.self),
                                              kCCKeySizeAES256)
    guard status == kCCSuccess else {
        throw Error.keyDerivationError
    }
}
```

The code from the question would look like:

```
let value = data.withUnsafeBytes { 
    $0.baseAddress?.assumingMemoryBound(to: UInt32.self)
}
```

In cases where the `'withUnsafeBytes' is deprecated: use withUnsafeBytes<R>(…)` warning persists, it seems like [the compiler can get confused when the closure has only one line](https://forums.swift.org/t/unsaferawbufferpointer-in-swift-5/22165/4). Making the closure have two or more lines might remove the ambiguity.

Comment: I used another way to implement the second example. This avoids using `withUnsafeMutableBytes`:  `var derivedKeyData = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: keyByteCount);let derivationStatus = CCKeyDerivationPBKDF(CCPseudoRandomAlgorithm(kCCPBKDF2),passphrase,passphrase.utf8.count,Array(salt),salt.count,hash,rounds,&derivedKeyData,derivedKeyData.count)`.

Comment: True, in some cases a pointer (indirection) to an allocated integer array works quite easer. Converting back and forth from Data to array of `UInt8` is also quite straightforward.

Comment: I get error : Value of type 'UnsafePointer<_>' has no member 'baseAddress'

Answer (score 7):

One more way to fix this warning to use **bindMemory(to:)**.

```
var rawKey = Data(count: rawKeyLength)
let status = rawKey.withUnsafeMutableBytes { rawBytes -> Int32 in
    guard let rawBytes = rawBytes.bindMemory(to: UInt8.self).baseAddress else {
        return Int32(kCCMemoryFailure)
    }
    return CCSymmetricKeyUnwrap(alg, ivBytes, iv.count, keyBytes, key.count, wrappedKeyBytes, wrappedKey.count, rawBytes, &rawKeyLength)
}
```

Comment: Instead of `rawBytes.bindMemory(to: UInt8.self).baseAddress` I think you want to use `rawBytes.baseAddress`, as the later one is always just a pointer to the very first data byte, ignoring any type or alignment requirement.

Answer (score 3):

I got this error as I was trying to figure out a compression stream tutorial. To get it to work, I added a step of converting the raw buffer pointer to a UnsafePointer

Original code from a tutorial I was working on.

--> where input: Data

--> where stream: compression_stream

```
//Method that shows the deprecation alert
return input.withUnsafeBytes { (srcPointer: UnsafePointer<UInt8>) in

//holder
var output = Data()

//Source and destination buffers
stream.src_ptr = srcPointer  //UnsafePointer<UInt8>
stream.src_size = input.count
… etc. 
}
```

Code with a conversion to make the above code work with a valid method

```
return input.withUnsafeBytes { bufferPtr in

//holder
var output = Data()

//Get the Raw pointer at the initial position of the UnsafeRawBuffer
let base: UnsafeRawPointer? = bufferPtr.baseAddress

//Unwrap (Can be combined with above, but kept it separate for clarity)
guard let srcPointer = base else {
   return output
}

//Bind the memory to the type
let count = bufferPtr.count
let typedPointer: UnsafePointer<UInt8> = srcPointer.bindMemory(to: UInt8.self, capacity: count)

// Jump back into the original method
stream.src_ptr = typedPointer  //UnsafePointer<UInt8>
}
```