# 'withUnsafeMutableBytes' is deprecated: use `withUnsafeMutableBytes<R>

Tags: swift5

I am very green with Xcode (apologize in advance).  Trying to bring some old code to life.  Getting the following with trying to move to Swift 5.

> withUnsafeMutableBytes' is deprecated: use `withUnsafeMutableBytes<R>(_: (UnsafeMutableRawBufferPointer) throws -> R) rethrows -> R` instead

Goal:  All I need to do is modify the code appropriately and be done.

I have looked at other Stack Overflow messages, searched various articles, experimented with different things, but can't quickly determine what needs to change.  I am sure the solution is super simple for someone that knows more.

```
var responseData = Data(count: Int(responseDataLength))

        _ = responseData.withUnsafeMutableBytes
        {
            mfError = MFMediaIDResponse_GetAsString(mfMediaIdResponsePtr.pointee, MFString($0), responseDataLength)
        }
```

Comment: Working on simple app with AM library.  For reference: func extractServerResponseFromMediaIdentificationResponse(mfMediaIdResponsePtr: UnsafeMutablePointer<MFMediaIDResponse?>, error: NSErrorPointer) -> AudioMagicIdServerResponse?
    {
      ...   var responseData = Data(count: Int(responseDataLength))

        _ = responseData.withUnsafeMutableBytes
        {
            mfError = MFMediaIDResponse_GetAsString(mfMediaIdResponsePtr.pointee, MFString($0), responseDataLength)
        }

       ...
    }

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Errors when update code to avoid deprecation warnings withUnsafeMutableBytes in swift 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55384250/errors-when-update-code-to-avoid-deprecation-warnings-withunsafemutablebytes-in)

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! I would like to help, but I don't understand the problem either. But maybe [this post](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/115227) can help you!

Comment: This could help https://forums.swift.org/t/withunsafebytes-data-api-confusion/22142

Comment: I believe I looked those links (stack overflow, swift, and apple) a few times.  I will work to review again and see what I need to do.  Given my experience, maybe I just don't get it.  I didn't get how those example mapped for me.

Answer (score 10):

Here is my example, when refreshing old code of `withUnsafeMutableBytes`

hope it helps

The old one:

```
_ = data.withUnsafeMutableBytes { (bytes: UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>) in
        memcpy((ioData.pointee.mBuffers.mData?.assumingMemoryBound(to: UInt8.self))!, bytes, dataCount)
    }
```

The new one:

```
_ = data.withUnsafeMutableBytes { (rawMutableBufferPointer) in
        let bufferPointer = rawMutableBufferPointer.bindMemory(to: UInt8.self)
        if let address = bufferPointer.baseAddress{
            memcpy((ioData.pointee.mBuffers.mData?.assumingMemoryBound(to: UInt8.self))!, address, dataCount)
        }
    }
```

---

Explains:

use `UnsafeMutablePointer<ContentType>`, you get an unsafeMutablePointer in its closure.

To access to its memory, so need to typed it with `bindMemory`,

more details on [Apple Pointer Doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/unsaferawpointer)