# Convert Data to Int64

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Is there a way to convert `Data` directly into `Int64`?

My solution is to convert Data -> String and then String -> Int64

```
let data = "123456".data(using: .utf8)! // data from string for example purposes


let idString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)! //IUO for example purposes too
let id = Int64(idString)
```

Comment: What is the issue you're facing?

Comment: What does the data contain? A *string* representation (as in your example) or a *binary* representation of the number?

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/q/55378409/1187415, https://stackoverflow.com/q/38023838/1187415

Answer (score 0):

have you tried with

```
let int64Value = data.withUnsafeBytes {
    $0.load(as: Int64.self)
}
```