# Deprecated withUnsafeBytes

Tags: ios, swift

I have the following extension:

```
extension UserDefaults {
    func color(forKey defaultName: String) -> UIColor? {
        guard let data = data(forKey: defaultName) else {
           return nil
        }
        let size = MemoryLayout<CGFloat>.size
        return UIColor(red:   data[size*0..<size*1].withUnsafeBytes{ $0.pointee },
                   green: data[size*1..<size*2].withUnsafeBytes{ $0.pointee },
                   blue:  data[size*2..<size*3].withUnsafeBytes{ $0.pointee },
                   alpha: data[size*3..<size*4].withUnsafeBytes{ $0.pointee })
    }
}
```

And Xcode is prompting me with the following warning:

`withUnsafeBytes is deprecated: use withUnsafeBytes<R>(_: (UnsafeRawBufferPointer) throws -> R) rethrows -> R instead`

for the `red`, `Green` and `blue` parameters.

I have tried to implement the suggested change but Xcode, no matter what, keeps showing me the warning; I might be doing something wrong that I cannot figure out.

I have tried other solutions, as described in other posts here, but it keeps warning me with that message.

I have read a `Swift` forum [thread](https://forums.swift.org/t/how-to-use-data-withunsafebytes-in-a-well-defined-manner/12811) regarding this and it seems it could be a bug within `swiftlang` itself.

Does anyone knows a workaround?

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but why are you using unsafe pointers for decoding when `CGFloat` conforms to `Codable`, so you could easily and safely encode/decode it to/from `Data`?

Comment: tbh somehow I forgot that option.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55378409/swift-5-0-withunsafebytes-is-deprecated-use-withunsafebytesr

Comment: thank's @MartinR. I'll close this post.
when searching this warning I didn't found that post you pointed.