# 'withUnsafeBytes' is deprecated: use `withUnsafeBytes<R>(_: (UnsafeRawBufferPointer)

Tags: swift

I got Xcode warning :

```
"'withUnsafeBytes' is deprecated: use withUnsafeBytes<R>(_: (UnsafeRawBufferPointer) throws -> R) rethrows -> R instead"
```

The code is :

```
_document = data.withUnsafeBytes({ (p: UnsafePointer<Int8>) -> htmlDocPtr? in
                return htmlReadMemory(p, Int32(data.count), nil, nil, 0)
            })
```

I'm more objective-c guy, and I stumble for 1 hour to shutdown this warning but no luck Any ideas ?

I already checked this answer :
[Swift 5.0: 'withUnsafeBytes' is deprecated: use `withUnsafeBytes<R>(...)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55378409/swift-5-0-withunsafebytes-is-deprecated-use-withunsafebytesr)

EDIT:
Also checked this and got the same warning :
https://github.com/leonbreedt/FavIcon/issues/23#issue-365477776

Comment: This is not reproduced (Change your code with this)  : https://github.com/leonbreedt/FavIcon/blob/e3bac1dc271feffba3bc38777e1a2d97d9af7ae7/Sources/FavIcon/HTML.swift#L34

Comment: Bingo. Thank you very much !
Can you answer in the right place so I will mark it is solved ?

Comment: *I already checked this answer*. The `baseAddress.assumingMemoryBound` solution is being suggested in the answer (which I marked as duplicate in your first, deleted question by the way).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the in the [doc](https://github.com/leonbreedt/FavIcon/blob/e3bac1dc271feffba3bc38777e1a2d97d9af7ae7/Sources/FavIcon/HTML.swift#L34)

you can change with this

```
_document = data.withUnsafeBytes { ptr in
    htmlReadMemory(ptr.baseAddress?.assumingMemoryBound(to: Int8.self), Int32(data.count), nil, nil, 0)
}
```

Comment: I think it would be better to return a value than to have an assignment side effect.