# Data withUnsafeBytes is deprecated

Tags: swift, bluetooth-lowenergy, unsafe-pointers, unsafe-unretained

I got this code here from an app I am working on. I inherited this code when the BLE guy left the team. I am not good with low level stuff and Data stuff. I am UI/UX front end person, and now I do need to get my hands dirty. This code is now a bit old and using deprecated code. I have unsuccessfully been trying to silence the warning, but I keep ending up with he same code or with errors.

This is the code that generates the warning. On the return line when using withUnsafeBytes

```
extension Data {
    func scanValueFromData<T>(start: Int = 0, invalid: T) -> (T, Int) {
        let length = MemoryLayout<T>.size
        guard self.count >= start + length else {
            return (invalid, start+length)
        }
        return (self.subdata(in: start..<start+length).withUnsafeBytes{ $0.pointee }, start+length)
    }
}
```

This method is used to decode a byte array to a struct. I get the data from a BLE service and the various vars are packed into an array of bytes.

If any one as a fix for this or a better way to do id.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55378409/swift-5-0-withunsafebytes-is-deprecated-use-withunsafebytesr ? The part `{ $0.pointee }` needs to be updated. "load as T"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The version of `withUnsafeBytes` that's deprecated here is the version which binds the underlying pointer to a known type ([`Data.withUnsafeBytes<R, T>(_ body: (UnsafePointer<T>) throws -> R) rethrows -> R`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/data/1780450-withunsafebytes)).

The preferred replacement is the version which does not bind in this way, and returns a raw buffer pointer ([`withUnsafeBytes<R>(_ body: (UnsafeRawBufferPointer) throws -> R) rethrows -> R`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/data/3139154-withunsafebytes)); luckily, transitioning between these only changes how you read from the pointer:

```
extension Data {
    func scanValueFromData<T>(start: Int = 0, invalid: T) -> (T, Int) {
        let length = MemoryLayout<T>.size
        guard self.count >= start + length else {
            return (invalid, start + length)
        }
    
        return (self.subdata(in: start ..< start + length).withUnsafeBytes { $0.load(as: T.self) }, start + length)
    }
}
```

Using [`UnsafeRawBufferPointer.load(as:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/unsaferawbufferpointer/2632297-load) you can safely read a trivial type `T` from the buffer. (Note that this method is *not* safe to call for non-trivial types, but this was true of the original version of the method too.)

If you want to simplify even a bit further, you can avoid repeating `start + length`:

```
func scanValueFromData<T>(start: Int = 0, invalid: T) -> (T, Int) {
    let length = MemoryLayout<T>.size
    var value = invalid
    if count >= start + length {
        value = subdata(in: start ..< start + length).withUnsafeBytes { $0.load(as: T.self) }
    }

    return (value, start + length)
}
```

or even shorter, at the cost of readability:

```
func scanValueFromData<T>(start: Int = 0, invalid: T) -> (T, Int) {
    let length = MemoryLayout<T>.size
    let value = count >= start + length ? subdata(in: start ..< start + length).withUnsafeBytes { $0.load(as: T.self) } : invalid
    return (value, start + length)
}
```

Comment: @LeoDabus True, but I wanted to keep the code change as minimal as possible. I can include a simplified version too.

Comment: IMO the size check shouldn't be part of the method. no need to use MemoryLayout  `extension Data {`
    `func object<T>(at index: Index = 0) -> T {`
        `subdata(in: index..<endIndex)`
        `.withUnsafeBytes { $0.load(as: T.self) }`
    `}`
`}`
`let uint16Max: UInt16 = Data([255,255,255,255]).object()`. // 65535

Comment: @LeoDabus The issue is with `Data` not large enough to load a value out of. `Data([]).object() as UInt16` will fatal-error with an out-of-bounds message. The check allows you to default more gracefully to another value

Comment: if you use `load(fromByteOffset: start)` without using subdata method you might get a misaligned error. **Swift/UnsafeRawPointer.swift:354: Fatal error: load from misaligned raw pointer**

Comment: The same would happen if you try to get an element from your collection using subscript with an invalid index. I think the check should be out of the method

Comment: @LeoDabus Sure, but this is in keeping with the original spirit of the question, not a suggestion to refactor all code paths to do this.

Comment: In any case, you're right — back to the subdata suggestion since it maintains compatibility.