# Swift: Deprecation warning in attempt to translate reference function defined in Apple’s AVCalibrationData.h file

Tags: ios, swift, camera-calibration

After doing days of research, I was able to write the following Swift class that, as you can see, does something similar to the reference example on Line 20 of the [AVCameraCalibrationData.h](https://github.com/xybp888/iOS-SDKs/blob/master/iPhoneOS13.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/Headers/AVCameraCalibrationData.h) file mentioned in [Apple’s WWDC depth data demo](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/507/) to demonstrate how to properly rectify depth data. It compiles fine, but with a deprecation warning denoted by a comment:

```
class Undistorter : NSObject {
    
    var result: CGPoint!
    
    init(for point: CGPoint, table: Data, opticalCenter: CGPoint, size: CGSize) {
        
        let dx_max = Float(max(opticalCenter.x, size.width - opticalCenter.x))
        let dy_max = Float(max(opticalCenter.y, size.width - opticalCenter.y))
        let max_rad = sqrt(pow(dx_max,2) - pow(dy_max, 2))
        
        let vx = Float(point.x - opticalCenter.x)
        let vy = Float(point.y - opticalCenter.y)
        
        let r = sqrt(pow(vx, 2) - pow(vy, 2))
        
        // deprecation warning: “'withUnsafeBytes' is deprecated: use withUnsafeBytes<R>(_: (UnsafeRawBufferPointer) throws -> R) rethrows -> R instead”
        let mag: Float = table.withUnsafeBytes({ (tableValues: UnsafePointer<Float>) in
            
            let count = table.count / MemoryLayout<Float>.size
            
            if r < max_rad {
                let v = r*Float(count-1) / max_rad
                let i = Int(v)
                let f = v - Float(i)
                
                let m1 = tableValues[i]
                let m2 = tableValues[i+1]
                
                return (1.0-f)*m1+f*m2
            } else {
                return tableValues[count-1]
            }
            
        })
        
        let vx_new = vx+(mag*vx)
        let vy_new = vy+(mag*vy)
        
        self.result = CGPoint(
            x: opticalCenter.x + CGFloat(vx_new),
            y: opticalCenter.y + CGFloat(vy_new)
        )
        
    }
}
```

Although this is a pretty common warning with a lot of examples in existence, I haven't found any examples of answers to the problem that fit this use case — all the examples that currently exist of people trying to get it to work involve networking contexts, <s>and attempting to modify this code to add the fixes in those locations in end up introducing errors. For example, on attempt to use [this fix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55378409/swift-5-0-withunsafebytes-is-deprecated-use-withunsafebytesr):</s>

```
let mag: Float = table.withUnsafeBytes { $0.load(as: Float) in // 6 errors introduced
```

So if there’s any way to fix this without introducing errors, I’d like to know.

Update: it actually does work; see my answer to my own question.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was simply a matter of adding one extra line:

```
let mag: Float = table.withUnsafeBytes {

    let tableValues = $0.load(as: [Float].self)
```

Now it compiles without incident.

Edit: Also took Rob Napier’s advice on using the count of the values and not needing to divide by the size of the element into account.

Comment: You're now making a copy of the data; is that ok for this use case? Sorry, for the typo: it's `baseAddress` not `basePointer`.

Answer (score -1):

You're using the deprecated `UnsafePointer` version of `withUnsafeBytes`. The new version passes `UnsafeBufferPointer`. So instead of this:

```
let mag: Float = table.withUnsafeBytes({ (tableValues: UnsafePointer<Float>) in
```

you mean this:

```
let mag: Float = table.withUnsafeBytes({ (tableValues: UnsafeBufferPointer<Float>) in
```

Instead of:

```
let count = table.count / MemoryLayout<Float>.size
```

(which was never legal, because you cannot access `table` inside of `table.withUnsafeBytes`), you now want:

```
let count = tableValues.count
```

There's no need to divide by the size of the element.

And instead of tableValues, you'll use `tableValues.baseAddress!`. Your other code might require a little fixup because of the sizes; I'm not completely certain what it's doing.

Comment: “Not completely certain what it’s doing” — that would be why Apple placed a commented out Objective-C version of exactly this [here](https://github.com/xybp888/iOS-SDKs/blob/master/iPhoneOS13.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/Headers/AVCameraCalibrationData.h), correct? Ended up solving my own problem anyway, see above.

Comment: I don't know what this comment means. I just wasn't clear what the `m1` and `m2` assignments are trying to do and whether that requires changing the offsets. Fixed the `basePointer` typo; it's `baseAddress`.

Comment: The `m1` and `m2` assignments correspond to the `mag_1` and `mag_2` assignments in Apple’s commented-out reference implementation where they’re specifically denoted with the `// Linear interpolation` comment on Line 154 of AVCalibrationData.h. You’d know what these assignments are trying to do if you just looked there.