# sprintf puts FF infront without any reason in C

Tags: c, microcontroller, led, lcd

I have this weird problem where I am using sprintf and it puts FF in front of the value I have.

(e.g.) I should get 01, but I am getting FF01

My code looks like this

```
while(1)
{

    if(getkey()=='g')
    {
       sprintf(str_2, "%X", ~OWReadByte());
       lcd_delay();
       lcd_string(str_2);
    }
}
```

I did some checking on the LEDs and on there i get the value i want, after using sprintf it just gets screwed up.

Comment: What values do `str_2` and `i` have?

Comment: What is the return type of `OWReadByte()`?  Hint: the `%02X` format specifier means that you print a *minimum* of two hexadecimal digits, *not* a maximum.

Comment: str_2 has a value of 8 and the value from OWReadByte is 8 bits long Int. I removed the i*2

Comment: Should `sprintf(str_2, "X", ~OWReadByte());` be `sprintf(str_2, "%X", ~OWReadByte());`

Comment: *"the value from `OWReadByte` is 8 bits long Int"*. Do you mean "8-bit `long Int`" or "8-bit long `Int`"? Please show the declaration of `OWReadByte`. Either way, it is not a `char` type so @mafso is correct. `~0xFE = 0xFF01`

Comment: It is just int, sorry for the confusion, as proof
int OWReadByte(void)

Comment: In that case please understand and accept the answer - you have to mask off the unwanted bits.

Comment: Do you want the "*one byte*" to be signed of unsigned? This is: do you want it to represent the values `0..255` or `-127..127`?

Comment: So i tried masking like this
`sprintf(str_2, "%X", (~OWReadByte()&0xFF));`
But, i am losing zeroes now.

Comment: @s3v3ns: For the zeros, you need a minimum field width of 2 and the  `0` flag (to pad with 0 instead of spaces): "%02X" ;)

Comment: That made it work, thanks. There is this 1 thing tho, but this is probably from my functions. From the example program that i have, i can see that the hexes are printed other way around (e.g.) i have B3 D4 DC 07 00 00  example has 00 00 07 DC D4 B3

Comment: That looks like an [endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) issue. A value and its representation are really two things. Anyway, that's a different question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The unary `~` operator changes the bits of the whole `int`, not only the lower 8 bits. `~0xfeu` (equivalently, `~0x00feu`) is `0xff01u` for 16-bit `int`.

I suggest to always use unsigned types when doing bit manipulation, passing a negative `int` to `%X` is, strictly speaking, undefined behavior.

To get rid of the higher bits, you can do

```
sprintf(&str_2[i * 2], "%02X", ~OWReadByte() & 0xffu);
```

Comment: It returns a int. Hex value that is 8 bits.

Comment: 8-bit types get promoted to `int` (and a value is a value, "hex" is a way to _represent_ certain values).

Comment: @s3v3ns the format specifiers cannot be used to truncate (except decimal places) - if the value does not fit the format, then the format breaks, not the value.

Comment: Well the whole idea is printing the hex value onto the LCD (I know hex and binary is pretty much the same). I said it the way I said it, because in my mind it made things a bit clearer.

Comment: Well i had never used format specifiers before and i just used them blindly out of frustrating in hopes they will work, i will edit the code so people can leave that part alone

Comment: It is important to correct the value, because i will be using OWReadByte a lot. But as i said, i am pretty sure the FF doesn't come from the function it self, because of the LEDs it is working just fine.
Of course that might be because it does not show the higher 8 bits on the LEDs.

Comment: @s3v3ns, I hadn't seen the edit of your comment... If it returns an `int`, then the same applies without integer promotions: `~0xfe` is `0xff01` (for a 16-bit `int`, and as a bit pattern, with two's complement, this is the value -255).

Comment: @WeatherVane: Thanks, precision for `d` conversion gives the minimum number of digits to appear, not a maximal width; I confused it with `s` conversion.

Comment: You are right in there, that it is 0xFE. So it has something to do with my functions?

Comment: It's the `~` operator. It operates on the whole `int`, not only on the lower 8 bits.

Comment: Are you sure the OP is interested in an unsigned 8bit integer and not in a signed one? Also why do you use the non-standard type `uint8_t` and not just `unsigned char`?

Comment: @alk, Initially, I thought, the return value would be `char` and OP is confused about integer promotions. But given that the function returns an `int` where only the lower 8 bits are used, I think OP wants positive values.

Comment: @alk, `uint8_t` is a standard type, but doesn't exist on machines with `CHAR_BIT` != 8, on which the code doesn't compile. With `unsigned char`, it would compile, but do the wrong thing. I currently wonder if the cast is a good suggestion anyway, maybe I'll remove it entirely.

Comment: Removed the cast, @alk. With the assumption that `OWReadByte` returns `unsigned char` (or `uint8_t` or whatever), the cast could be thought of as "convert back to what it was before promotion and what it is supposed to be". Given that it returns `int`, "mask off the higher bits" is the more straight-forward way, I think. (And it avoids the off-topic discussion if `%X` requires `(unsigned)(unsigned char)~OWReadByte()`.)

Comment: What about: `... "%02hhX", ~OWReadByte());` :-) And btw: `uint8_t` is POSIX not C.

Comment: @alk, `%hhX` looks good (maybe with an `unsigned char` cast). Is this a real suggestion for the answer or just discussing for the sake of having a discussion? Just wondering, I don't have a problem with the latter :) `uint8_t` is C99; it is optional, though (POSIX requires it, iirc), but the standard is quite clear that an implementation should provide it wherever possible. Given that `typedef unsigned char uint8_t;` is a valid way to provide this type on any machine with `CHAR_BIT` == 8, I think this type can be assumed to exist if (and only if) a `char` has 8 bits.

Comment: You are correct, the `[u]int[N]_t` are an optional part of the C-Standard.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming at least C99 the most simple and straight forward to fix the observed issue is to specify the correct *length modifer(s)*.

```
sprintf(..., "%hhX", ~OWReadByte());
```

No casting, no precision is necessary.

Comment: `%hX` is for `unsigned short`, which has at least 16 bits.

Comment: Then a `short` has the same range as `int`.

Comment: Are sure this is the case for a 16bit platform?

Comment: Just don't try %hhX in Microsoft's compiler -- they don't support hh!

Comment: Ok, makeing my answer less precise on the effects of `h`.

Comment: @SteveValliere, `%hhX` is C99, Microsoft's C library only supports C89. (Could be pointed out, perhaps, but C99 usually is considered "the" C on SO anyway.)

Comment: @alk, on a standard conforming platform, `short` must have at least 16 bit (see n1570 5.2.4.2.1), so `h` has basically no effect on `X` conversions on a 16-bit platform. In case you're interested in language-layerism, maybe have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4586962/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-h-and-hh-modifiers-for-printf) for why an `unsigned char` cast might be required by a strict reading of the standard. (I don't consider this a real-world issue, so +1 for the alternative approach.)

Comment: Added the missing, but necessary note on C99. @mafso: Thanks for pointing this out.