# Why wasn't a specifier for `float` defined in `printf`?

Tags: c, floating-point, printf, c-standard-library

It looks like it could have been, there are (at least in C99) length modifiers that can be applied to `int`: `%hhd`, `%hd`, `%ld` and `%lld` mean `signed char`, `short`, `long` and `long long`. There is even a length modifier applicable to `double`: `%Lf` means `long double`.

The question is **why** did they omit `float`? Following the pattern, it might have been `%hf`.

Comment: @Seb I got the format specifiers from the "wrong" place. Some implementation seem to accept `%lf` for `long double`, the standard however specifies `%Lf` for that. I've updated the question.

Comment: ... and `%Ld` does not mean `long`, either. What that means is [*undefined behaviour*](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fprintf.html#7.21.6.1p9) (the same section and paragraph as passing an incorrect argument renders your previous `%lf` -> `long double` correspondence undefined). Note the lack of pattern?

Comment: @skyking Which implementation would that be?

Comment: @Seb Don't know, it may even be that I misread my source.

Comment: @skyking Why `%hf` and not `%Hf`, to align with the capital `L` in `%Lf`? Surely you see that the pattern used for integer specifiers doesn't apply for `float` specifiers, now, right?

Comment: Related to [Why does printf() promote a float to a double?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28097564/1708801)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does scanf() need "%lf" for doubles, when printf() is okay with just "%f"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/210590/why-does-scanf-need-lf-for-doubles-when-printf-is-okay-with-just-f)

Comment: @Seb: In fact `%lf` stands for `long float`, which was in early version of C a synonym for `double`. Now historical vestige, but it prevented the scheme to be minimally coherent when the committee introduced `long double` in C89. And no, there are no real pattern; which does not prevent asking for a way to format float values.

Comment: @AntoineL Are you reading any particular manual, or is that just a guess? Because the manuals I'm reading ([the POSIX standard (part of the Single Unix Specification)](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fprintf.html) and [the C11 standard, section 7.21.6.1, paragraph 7](http://www.iso-9899.info/n1570.html#7.21.6.1p7)) both state quite clearly that the `l` length modifier "has no effect on a following `a`, `A`, `e`, `E`, `f`, `F`, `g`, or `G` conversion specifier."

Comment: @Seb: I was (unobviously?) speaking about `scanf` specifier, so next subclause applies. About `long float`, see for example [C99 Rationale](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/C99RationaleV5.10.pdf), page 42. What _would be_ a guess could be to decide whether the ANSI committee added explicit `%lf` to `printf` (it was [undefined behaviour (by omission) in V7](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=printf&manpath=Unix+Seventh+Edition)) to either cater with then-existing usage for `long float`, to align with `scanf`, or if both apply.

Comment: @AntoineL Ah, I see what you were saying, but "`%lf` once stood for `long float`" is quite different to "`%lf` stands for `long float`". At the time when the word "animal", already widely known as a Latin word, was adopted into English, there was a native word "deer" which had the same meaning. After "animal" came in as a general term, the word "deer" developed it's specialised meaning of "a horned beast". It might be a good idea to consider this a similar form of evolution; if you use "deer" in the old context you are speaking *Old English*, which is very different to the English of today...

Comment: @AntoineL ... and similarly, `long float` is in the context of *Old C* (ancient, in fact, since it's pre-C89), which is very different to the C of today (decidedly not-C, in fact).

Answer (score 46):

Because in C variadic function calls, any `float` argument is promoted (i.e. converted) to a `double`, so `printf` is getting a `double` and would use `va_arg(arglist, double)` to get it inside its implementation.

In the past (C89 and K&R C) every `float` argument was converted to a `double`. The current standard omits this promotion for fixed arity functions which have an explicit prototype. It is related to (and details are explained in) the [ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface) & [calling conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention) of the implementation. Practically speaking, a `float` value would be often loaded into a double-floating point register when passed as an argument, but details can vary. Read the Linux [x86-64 ABI specification](http://www.x86-64.org/documentation_folder/abi.pdf) as an example.

Also, there is no practical reason to give a specific format control string for `float` since you can adjust the width of the output (e.g. with `%8.5f`) as wanted, and `%hd` is much more useful (nearly necessary) in `scanf` than in `printf`

Beyond that, **I guess that the reason** (to omit `%hf` specifying `float` -promoted to `double` in caller- in `printf`) **is historical**: at first, C was a system programming language, not an HPC one (Fortran was preferred in HPC perhaps till the late 1990s) and `float` was not very important; it was (and still is) thought of like `short`, a way to lower memory consumption. And today's FPUs are fast enough (on desktop or server computers) to avoid using `float` except as a mean to use less memory. You basically should believe that every `float` is somewhere (perhaps *inside* the FPU or the CPU) converted to `double`.

Actually, your question might be paraphrased as : why `%hd` exists for `printf` (where it is basically useless, since `printf` is getting an `int` when you pass it some `short`; however `scanf` needs it!). I don't know why, but I imagine than in system programming it might be more useful.

You could spend time lobbying the next ISO C standard to get `%hf` accepted by `printf` for `float` (promoted to `double` at `printf` calls, like `short`-s get promoted to `int`), with undefined behavior when the double precision value is out of bound for `float`-s, and symetrically `%hf` accepted by `scanf` for `float` pointers. Good luck on that.

Comment: That doesn't explain everything for `printf`, though. There is also argument promotion of all narrow types to `int`, but still there are special format modifiers for them.

Comment: But for the small integer type format specifier, the C standard addresses promotion. See for example 7.19.6.1 fprintf: `hh Specifies that a following d, i, o, u, x, or X conversion specifier applies to a
signed char or unsigned char argument (the argument will have
been promoted according to the integer promotions, but its value shall be converted to signed char or unsigned char before printing);`. So I don't believe this has anything to do with implicit type promotion.

Comment: @Lundin This is an excellent observation! It's enough to remove the last bit of doubt from this answer.

Comment: What you have not seen here, which Lundin mentioned, is the secondary conversion within `printf`. Values outside of the range of `short` will be converted, in an implementation-defined manner, down to `short`. This is actually very well defined for `unsigned` types and their corresponding specifiers. What purpose would such a narrowing conversion from `double` (as passed to `printf`) to `short` have, when the corresponding behaviour is undefined?

Comment: Concerning "there is no practical reason to give a specific format control string for `float`".  In corner cases, some sort of `"%ha"` could be useful to display `float` aligned in a different fashion `printf("%a %ha\n", FLT_MAX, FLT_MAX) --> 0x1.fffffep+127 0x0.ffffffp+128` as that pesky `e` in the first case only have 3 significant bits.

Comment: [What is the purpose of the h and hh modifiers for printf?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4586962/995714)

Comment: (continue) This right-justified alignment is some times employed when printing `long double` with `"%La"` and when it has 64 bits of precision, a leading 0 is used.

Comment: I would disagree with "today's FPUs are fast enough (on desktop or server computers) to avoid using `float` except as a mean to use less memory". `float` is still very widely used in high-performance applications where double precision is not needed. While double-precision processing is quite fast nowadays, single precision operations often provide twice the throughput on SIMD architectures (the same register can hold twice the number of elements). Plus, the smaller memory footprint can yield huge benefits when caching is taken into account.

Comment: @Jason R The ideas about "single precision operations often provide twice the throughput" and "the smaller memory footprint" bolsters this answer's to "avoid using `float` except as a mean to use less memory" as less memory usage readily equates to higher throughput.

Comment: @chux: I disagree; the answer specifically implies that speed isn't a reason to choose `float` above `double`, which just isn't true.

Comment: All C standards including C89 allow prototypes, and convert to the declared type for prototyped parameters, but default-promote 
vararg arguments and all arguments to an unprototyped (K&R1) function.
Only pre-C89 (K&R1 and pre-K&R1) has no prototypes and thus always default-promotes.

Comment: for your last question on `..however scanf needs it!` **maybe** because `scanf` need to know the size in bytes for what it will be reading from an input stream, where `printf` wouldn't have issues outputting a `short` as an `int` because it won't show trailing unused zeroes beyond `short` range, which won't seem to exist since it's becoming part of an output stream of characters.

Answer (score 15):

Because of **default argument promotions**.

`printf()` is a variable argument function (`...` in its signature), all `float` arguments are promoted to `double`.

> #### C11 §6.5.2.2 Function calls
>
> 6 If the expression that denotes the called function has a type that does not include a prototype, the integer promotions are performed on each argument, and arguments that have type `float` are promoted to `double`. These are called the default argument promotions.
>
> 7 The ellipsis notation in a function prototype declarator causes
> argument type conversion to stop after the last declared parameter. The default argument promotions are performed on trailing arguments.

Comment: That doesn't explain everything, though. There is also argument promotion of all narrow types to `int`, but still there are special format modifiers for them.

Comment: This quote is also irrelevant, it just describes the default argument promotions. People got to stop upvoting just because someone quotes a random part of the standard... actually read what it says before you do. The part that is relevant and actually says that the default argument promotions apply to variadic functions is found further down, in 6.5.2.2/7: "The ellipsis notation in a function prototype declarator causes argument type conversion to stop after the last declared parameter. The default argument promotions are performed on trailing arguments."

Comment: @Lundin I've added 6.5.2.2/7. Section 6 explains how `float` promoted to `double` in default argument promotions, section 7 explains how `...` performs default argument promotions. My previous answer was incomplete, yes, and it still is, but I don't think saying it's irrelevant/random is fair.

Comment: "The question is why did they omit float?" to which you answered "because of default argument promotions" followed by a quote of how default argument promotions work in the absence of a function prototype. That's rather random to me.

Comment: @Jens Gustedt Strictly, there are no special format modifiers for _narrow_ integers  `"%hd"`, `"%hhu"`, etc. take an `int`, `unsigned` argument.   It is that the modifiers narrow the `int`, `unsigned` to `shiort int`, `unsigned char` _after_ receiving them at the full width.

Comment: @chux The question is still why there isn't one that does the same thing to a double argument.

Comment: @Random832 The answer is because there's an implementation-defined (or in case of `unsigned` types, well defined) narrowing conversion for the integer types, and the same narrowing is **undefined** for floating point types.

Comment: @Seb it's still well defined for values that can be represented in the narrower type.

Comment: @Random832 my point is there's a pattern you've no doubt spotted which is the `h` suffix reduces values beyond the range modulo whatever`_MAX`  for `unsigned` types, and in an implementation-defined manner for the signed integer types. This reduction isn't well defined for floating types as you just clarified... the `h` suffix is meant to do exactly that. If that can't be done without UB then it's inconsistent. Inconsistency in C is the reason we're having this discussion; perhaps we should all just use Java ;)

Comment: @Seb yeah but C doesn't in general shy away from having features which would cause undefined behavior if used with the wrong values... just in printf itself (or, rather, in varargs functions as a whole) you're free to use %o/%u/%x with signed values as long as they happen to be positive but it's undefined if they're negative.

Comment: @Random832 Those all have unique functionality attached to them, and the UB is due to conflicting representations between signed and unsigned types. What you're proposing already exists as `%f` with the caveat that values outside of range don't invoke UB.

Answer (score 10):

Due to the default argument promotions when calling variadic functions, **`float` values are implicitly converted to `double`** before the function call, and **there is no way to pass a `float` value to `printf`**. Since there's no way to pass a `float` value to `printf`, there's no need for an explicit format specifier for `float` values.

Having said that, [AntoineL](https://stackoverflow.com/users/656988/antoinel) brought up an interesting point in a comment that `%lf` (currently used in `scanf` to correspond to an argument type `double *`) may have once stood for "`long float`", which was a type synonym in pre-C89 days, according to page 42 of [the C99 rationale](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/C99RationaleV5.10.pdf). By that logic, it might make sense that `%f` was intended to stand for a `float` value which has been converted to a `double`.

---

Regarding the `hh` and `h` length modifiers, `%hhu` and `%hu` present a well-defined use-case for these format specifiers: You can print the least significant byte of a large `unsigned int` or `unsigned short` without a cast, for example:

```
printf("%hhu\n", UINT_MAX); // This will print (unsigned char)  UINT_MAX
printf("%hu\n",  UINT_MAX); // This will print (unsigned short) UINT_MAX
```

It isn't particularly well defined what a narrowing conversion from `int` to `char` or `short` will result in, but it is at least *implementation-defined*, meaning the implementation is required to actually document this decision.

> Following the pattern it should have been `%hf`.

Following the pattern you've observed, `%hf` should convert values outside of the range of `float` back to `float`. However, that kind of narrowing conversion from `double` to `float` [results in undefined behaviour](http://www.iso-9899.info/n1570.html#6.3.1.5), and there's no such thing as an `unsigned float`. The pattern you see doesn't make sense.

---

To be formally correct, `%lf` does not denote a `long double` argument, and if you were to pass a `long double` argument [you would be invoking undefined behaviour](http://www.iso-9899.info/n1570.html#7.21.6.1p9). It is explicit from [the documentation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fprintf.html) that:

> `l` (ell)
>       ... has no effect on a following `a`, `A`, `e`, `E`, `f`, `F`, `g`, or `G` conversion specifier.

I'm surprised nobody else has picked up on this? `%lf` denotes a `double` argument, just like `%f`. If you want to print a `long double`, use `%Lf` (capital ell).

It should henceforth make sense that `%lf` for both `printf` and `scanf` correspond to `double` and `double *` arguments... `%f` is exceptional only because of the default argument promotions, for the reasons mentioned earlier.

... and `%Ld` does not mean `long`, either. What that means is [*undefined behaviour*](http://www.iso-9899.info/n1570.html#7.21.6.1p9).

Comment: But a `short` gets promoted to an `int`  when used as a variadic argument to `printf` and `%hd` exists

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch The OPs question is "why did they omit `float`?"... Not "why didn't they omit `short`?". Your concern seems irrelevant to me, but if you really want me to, just bark and I'll explain why that may be so.

Comment: My point is that following your argument, there is no way to pass a `short` value to `printf`, however `%hd` exists for `printf`!

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch How's that?

Comment: `printf` is getting an `int` when you pass it some `short`  value.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch It sure is, and that `int` value is then converted back to a `short` value... in an implementation-defined manner, when it's outside of range. If there were a `%hf`, then passing a `double` value that's similarly out of range can only result in undefined behaviour.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Why does `%hd` exist?  Try `short x = -72; printf( "%x\n", x );` and compare the result to `short x = -72; printf("%hx\n", x);`

Comment: @Seb: Strictly speaking, `%hd` and `%hhd` are probably not useful for `printf` -- but they're harmless, and perhaps useful as documentation, when passing values of type `short` and `signed char`. And `%hn` and `%hhn` are useful. They're also useful for `scanf`, which works with objects rather than values and so are not subject to promotion.

Comment: @KeithThompson I can agree with regards to `%hd` and `%hhd`, but I think `%hu` and `%hhu` might present more of a valid usecase... hence the reason I mentioned those explicitly (don't know if you realised that?)

Comment: I think `printf("%hhu\n", UINT_MAX);` is UB, the standard says that the corresponding argument must have been `char` (possibly signed/unsigned) before promotion

Comment: @M.M Where does the standard say that?

Comment: @Seb "`hh` Specifies that a following d, i, o, u, x, or X conversion specifier applies to a signed char or unsigned char argument"

Comment: @M.M According to [part 2 of the ISO/IEC directives](http://www.iec.ch/members_experts/refdocs/iec/isoiec-dir2%7Bed6.0%7Den.pdf), that doesn't contain a valid verbal form for expression of provisions. See "Annex H" for keywords that must be present.

Comment: In that case it'd be undefined behaviour by omission , since it is not specified what `hh` applies to. I don't want to have a protracted argument here, since the text is way too imprecise , these arguments can go on forever with the parties not reaching any agreement.

Answer (score 5):

From the ISO C11 standard, `6.5.2.2 Function calls /6` and `/7`, discussing function calls in the context of expressions (my emphasis):

> 6/ If the expression that denotes the called function has a type that does not include a prototype, the integer promotions are performed on each argument, and ***arguments that have type float are promoted to double. These are called the default argument promotions.***
>
> 7/ If the expression that denotes the called function has a type that does include a prototype, the arguments are implicitly converted, as if by assignment, to the types of the corresponding parameters, taking the type of each parameter to be the unqualified version of its declared type. The ellipsis notation in a function prototype declarator causes
>   argument type conversion to stop after the last declared parameter. ***The default argument promotions are performed on trailing arguments.***

This means that any `float` arguments after the `...` in the prototype are converted to `double` and the `printf` family of calls are defined that way (`7.21.6.11` et seq):

```
int fprintf(FILE * restrict stream, const char * restrict format, ...);
```

So, since there's no way for `printf()`-family calls to actually *receive* a float, it makes little sense to have a special format specifier (or modifier) for it.

Comment: We might have in the standard something like: `%hf` convert the `double` value into a `float` and displays it with reduced precision. BTW, `%hd` has an equivalent meaning (since `printf` does not get a `short` neither)

Comment: But `printf` is not receiving a `short` neither!

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch You're playing a broken record. I've already explained the rationale behind `%hd` when you copy/pasted that same comment into the section for my answer... and that has nothing to do with the question asked here. Do note that by *question* I mean "the string of words ending with a question mark".

Answer (score 2):

Considering `scanf` has separate format specifiers for float, double, or long double, I don't see why `printf` and similar functions weren't implemented in a similar way, but that's how C / C++ and the standards ended up.

There can be an issue with the minimum size for a push or pop operation depending on the processor and the current mode, but this could have been handled with default padding, similar to default alignment of local variables or variables in a structure. Microsoft dropped support for 80 bit (10 byte) `long double`s when it went from 16 bit to 32 / 64 bit compilers, now treating `long double`s the same as `double`s (64 bit / 8 byte). They could have padded them to 12 or 16 byte boundaries as needed, but this wasn't done.

Comment: The difference is that `scanf` expects a pointer argument when accepting a `float`. The same type promotion doesn't happen when calling `scanf`.

Comment: @skyking - I understand that, but type promotion could have been originally specified to handle more cases, and the format specifiers from scanf were already defined.

Comment: There's not much type promotion that could be done on a pointer (more than perhaps promoting it to a far pointer). Changing the type of the target is a bad idea, first of all it would mean that you may get a buffer overrun when you dereference a pointer to 16-bit data as if it was 32 bits. In addition you cannot do it the other way either if you have middle endian.

Comment: @skyking - I meant type promotion for parameters for functions like printf. scanf requires specific format specifiers for each target type.

Answer (score 2):

Reading the C rationale, below fscanf, the following can be found:

> A new feature of C99: The hh and ll length modifiers were added in
>   C99. ll supports the new long long int type. hh adds the ability to
>   treat character types the same as all other integer types; this can be
>   useful in implementing macros such as SCNd8 in  (see
>   7.18).

So supposedly the `hh` was added for the purpose of providing support for all of the new `stdint.h` types. This could explain why a length modifier was added for small integers but not for small floats.

It doesn't explain why C90 inconsistently had `h` but no `hh` though. The language as specified in C90 is not always consistent, simple as that. And later versions have inherited the inconsistency.

Answer (score 2):

When C was invented, all floating-point values were converted to a common type (i.e. `double`) before being used in computations or passed to functions (including) `printf`, so there was no need for `printf` to make any distinctions among floating-point types.

In the interest of promoting arithmetic efficiency and accuracy, the IEEE-754 floating-point standard defined an 80-bit type which was larger than a normal 64-bit `double` but could be processed faster.  The intention was that given an expression like `a=b+c+d;` it would be both faster and more accurate to convert everything to an 80-bit type, add together three 80-bit numbers, and convert the result to a 64-bit type, than to compute the sum `(b+c)` as a 64-bit type and then add that to `d`.

In the interest of supporting the new type, ANSI C defined a new type `long double` which implementations could have refer to the new 80-bit type or a 64-bit `double`.  Unfortunately, even though the *purpose* of the IEEE-754 80-bit type was to have all values automatically promote to the new type the way they had been promoted to `double`, ANSI made it so the new type gets passed to `printf` or other variadic methods differently from other floating-point types, thus making such automatic promotion untenable.

Consequently, both floating-point types that existed when C was created can use the same `%f` format specifier, but the `long double` that was created afterward requires a different `%Lf` format specifier (with an *uppercase* `L`).

Answer (score 2):

`%hhd`, `%hd`, `%ld` and `%lld` were added to `printf` to make the format strings more consistent with `scanf`, even though they are redundant for `printf` because of the default argument promotions.

So why wasn't `%hf` added for `float`? That's easy: looking at `scanf`'s behaviour, `float` already has a format specifier. It's `%f`. And the format specifier for `double` is `%lf`.

That `%lf` is exactly what C99 added to `printf`. Prior to C99, the behaviour of `%lf` was undefined (by omission of any definition in the standard). As of C99, it's a synonym for `%f`.