# Using %f but get "format %f expects type double"

Tags: c, floating-point, embedded, printf

Unless I'm tired I do not understand the following warning. I am not sure what the compiler is based on (it's MPLAB X 6 using XC16 from Microchip for a dsPIC33 microcontroller).

```
float test=5.5;
printf("%f\n", test);
warning: format '%f' expects type 'double', but argument 2 has type 'float'
```

Normally `%f` is for float and `%lf` for double, right ? `%hf` does not exist, so how can I make this warning go away without doing `printf("%f\n", (double)test)`

My question is somewhat related to [Why wasn't a specifier for `float` defined in `printf`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32517932/why-wasnt-a-specifier-for-float-defined-in-printf)

Comment: Actually, for vararg functions like `printf` all floating point types smaller than `double` should be *promoted* to `double`. For `printf` there's no difference between `%f` and `%lf`. This seems to be a false positive, unless the compiler doesn't do the promotion of `test` to a `double`, in which case the compiler is incorrect.

Comment: Anyways, you can probably satisfy your finicky compiler if you simply cast `test` to `double`.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: The first sentence of the accepted answer says why `%f` takes a `double` argument, and that a `float` argument is automatically converted to `double`. It does not answer the question here about why the compiler is complaining that a `float` argument is passed.

Comment: @thebusybee This is **not** a dupe of that question.  It's impossible to pass a `float` to a varargs function such as `printf()` in standard-compliant C as a `float` will be promoted to `double`, thus the warning is nonsensical.  This looks like a non-standard compiler, or a compiler with a bug.

Comment: It seems that the comopiler it is `gcc` (from [this documentation](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/50002071K.pdf)). So I really wonder that it issues this warning. Do `printf("%f\n", (double)test)` and `printf("%f\n", test)` behave the same at runtime?

Comment: To all dupeclosevoters: It's definitely not a dupe of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32517932/why-wasnt-a-specifier-for-float-defined-in-printf) even it it looks like one at first glance.

Comment: Probably a bug, but it could be an intentional deviation from the standard if doubles aren't a superset of floats on that platform? Seems unlikely, though.

Comment: Don't know if this is the issue: failure to `#include <stdio.h>` is UB (I mean, calling `printf()` without a valid prototype in scope is UB)

Comment: Did you check the compiler's documentation for statements about standard conformity? What does it say?

Comment: @pmg A missing `#include <stdio.h>` could very well cause this.  An implicit declaration would not be a varargs function, and would not promote `float` to `double`. That looks like an answer to me...

Comment: @pmg The OP could check that _with_ the include the warning disappears... Then this is the answer.

Comment: If the reason is a missing #include, then there should be a prior warning that OP has ignored and asked about the consequences, that is not a good question, is rather a typo.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: A missing `#include <stdio.h>` would not cause this. With an implicit declaration, the behavior would not be defined by the C standard because C 2018 6.5.2.2 7 says if the calling expression has a type that does not include a prototype but the function definition has a prototype with `...`, the behavior is undefined. But the compiler would not diagnose this as passing a `float` where a `double` is expected, particularly since a `float` is promoted to `double` both for a function without a prototype and for arguments corresponding to `...`.

Comment: @dargaud, Do you still receive that message with a prior `#include <stdio.h>`?

Comment: @EricPostpischil Which means buggy compiler then?

Comment: @dargaud, "Normally %f is for float and %lf for double, right ?" --> No.  `l` is optional for either one when using the standard C library.

Comment: `#include <stdio.h>` is present, and no change if I remove it. If I cast to `(double)` the warning goes away. So the consensus seems that it's a compiler bug ?

Comment: @dargaud For you, what does `printf("%ld\n", __STDC_VERSION__);` print?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a compiler bug. The MPLAB compilers are notorious for their very poor C standard compliance. On the Microchip forums there are lots of very old threads reporting the very same issue ([example](https://forum.microchip.com/s/topic/a5C3l000000MXBcEAO/t357628) [example](https://forum.microchip.com/s/topic/a5C3l000000MHBNEA4/t296109)).

As noted in comments, `printf` is a variadic function an all parameters passed to it are subject to something called "the default argument promotions", which in this case means that a passed `float` will *always* get implicitly promoted to `double` when passed to `printf`.

And so because of these mandatory default argument promotions, you *can't* pass a `float` no matter what you try. The C standard doesn't even mention `float` for this reason, example from C17 7.21.6.1 §8:

> `f,F`
> A `double` argument...

---

Unrelated to your question, you do already mix `float` and `double` here: `float test=5.5;`. The `5.5` constant is of type `double` - `5.5f` gives a  `float`.

You should make it a habit to never mix `float`, `double` or integer operands in the same expression because of the various subtle implicit promotion rules of C.

Comment: Is it a bug, or just an annoying design decision? It is a warning, not an error after all.  It is not saying it is semantically or syntactically incorrect.  On low end MCUs you might want a warning that a 32 bit type has been promoted to 64 bits.  You might also want a means to suppress it.  In any event use of any FP on such a part is likely ill-advised.

Comment: @Clifford It's a crystal clear bug; how these functions work has been known since the dawn of time and should come as no surprise to anyone, least of all to someone attempting to design a compiler. It has always been impossible to pass a float to `printf`, which is the very reason why `%lf` didn't even exist in ancient C90. Those using floating point and `printf` on low-end MCUs deserve what's coming to them.

Comment: But as I understand it, the code compiles and runs correctly. Issuing of a warning is not in itself a bug. That not to say the warning is not rather pointless of course.

Comment: @Clifford It doesn't exactly build confidence in the compiler. And apparently bugs don't get fixed either.

Comment: In that we are in complete agreement, horrible chips with quirky compilers.

Answer (score 0):

> Normally `%f` is for `float` and `%lf` for `double`, right ?

No.

---

With `printf()` and friends, `"%f"` and `"%lf"` are both for `double`.

> "l (ell) ... has no effect on a following a, A, e, E, f, F, g, or G conversion
> specifier."
> C Spec: The fprintf function

`float` arguments to a `...` function like `int printf(const char * restrict format, ...);` are first converted to a `double` and it is a `double` that `printf()` receives.

---

With `scanf()` and friends, `"%f"` matches a `float *` and `"%lf"` matches a `double *`.

---

> how can I make this warning go away without doing `printf("%f\n", (double)test)`

- The warning does not follow the C spec.  See if that particular warning can be disabled.
- Use a compliant compiler.
- Of course one could change code: make `test` a `double`, don't use `printf()`, ...