# C - printf() interchangeability of specifiers

Tags: c

Is there any reason to choose

```
printf("%hhx", foo);
```

over

```
printf("%x", foo);
```

Here *foo* is an unsigned char.
I've conducted some tests and they appear to be interchangeable, is that really the case? If so, which one should use when bearing portability in mind?

Comment: Type of `foo` is?

Comment: What is the type of `foo` ? Did you carefully read documentation of [printf](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) ?

Comment: @coderredoc sorry, just fixed that

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4586962/11683 probably answers your question.

Comment: Only makes a difference if `foo` is a `signed char` and has a negative value, e.g. `char foo = 0xee;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the specific case of `unsigned char foo`, there isn't a difference.  If you tried:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
      signed char bar = '\xFF';
    unsigned char foo = '\xFF';
    printf("%hhx %x\n", bar, bar);
    printf("%hhx %x\n", foo, foo);
    return 0;
}
```

You'd typically get the output:

```
ff ffffffff
ff ff
```

The reason is that in both cases, the character is converted to an `int` when it is passed to `printf()`, but the signed character is converted to a negative `int`, which is then processed by conversion to `unsigned char` when the length modifier is `hh` and is left at full size (4 bytes, I'm assuming) when the length modifier is omitted.

Comment: isn't `hh` a type modifier though?

Comment: In the standard ([C11 §7.21.6.1 The `printf` function ¶4 — also ¶7](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.1p4)), the qualifiers such as `hh` are specifically called _length modifiers._