# Does using tag `h` or `hh` in `printf` involves undefined behaviour?

Tags: c++, c, printf, language-lawyer

For example such code may be useful:

```
unsigned char ch = 0xf2;
printf("%02hhx", ch);
```

However, `ch` is promoted to `int` when passing as a parameter of variadic function `printf`. So when `%hhx` is used, there is type mismatch. Is any undefined behavior involved here according to C standard? What if it is C++?

There are some discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4586962/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-h-and-hh-modifiers-for-printf) but no answer is given.

Comment: There is no type mismatch.  The `hhx` code inside `printf()` converts the `int` to `unsigned char` and proceeds from there.

Comment: What "type mismatch" are you talking about? `printf` is perfectly aware of default argument promotions. And `%hhx` expects an `int` argument. `%hhx` affects the output spec only, but the argument it receives is still an `int`.

Comment: `ch` can be promoted to `unsigned int` when `UCHAR_MAX>INT_MAX`. This implies `sizeof(int)==1` and therefore it is not really promoted since on such a system `unsigned char` would be the same as `unsigned int`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C11 standard says:

> **7.21.6.1/7**
>   `hh` Specifies that a following `d`, `i`, `o`, `u`, `x`, or `X` conversion specifier applies to a signed char or unsigned char argument (the argument will have
>   been promoted according to the integer promotions, but its value shall be
>   converted to signed char or unsigned char before printing); or that
>   a following n conversion specifier applies to a pointer to a signed char
>   argument.

So no, there is no undefined behavior. The standard is well aware that a `char` argument to a variadic function would be promoted to `int`.