# Why does printf's hh and h length modifiers exist?

Tags: c, printf, variadic-functions, integer-promotion

In variadic functions, default argument promotions occur.

> 6.5.2.2.6 If the expression that denotes the called function has a type that does not include a prototype, the integer promotions are performed on each argument, and arguments that have type `float` are promoted to `double`. These are called the *default argument promotions*. [...]

> 6.5.2.2.7 [...] The ellipsis notation in a function prototype declarator causes argument type conversion to stop after the last declared parameter. The default argument promotions are performed on trailing arguments.

Therefore,

```c
signed char c = 123;
int         i = 123;
float       f = 123;
double      d = 123;

printf("%d\n", i);   // ok
printf("%d\n", c);   // ok, even though %d expects int.
printf("%f\n", d);   // ok
printf("%f\n", f);   // ok, even though %f expects double.
```

So why is there a `printf` length modifier for `char` (`hh`) and `short` (`h`)?

---

Section number refer to N2176.

Comment: Try `signed char` or `short` values the the most significant bit set....

Comment: These modifiers tell `printf()` to undo the default promotions, to get the original `char` or `short` value.

Comment: @Andrew Henle, Re "*Try `signed char` or `short` values the the most significant bit set...*", Those work perfectly fine with `%d`. `(signed char)-1` and `(short)-1` get promoted to `(int)-1`, which `%d` handles perfectly fine. Did you make a mistake?

Comment: @Barmar, Re "*These modifiers tell printf() to undo the default promotions, to get the original char or short value.*", What is there to undo? Integer promotions have no effect on the value

Comment: Symmetry with `scanf()`.  Same for `l` in `"%lf"`.

Comment: And the same for `%i` and `%d`. These do the same thing in `printf()`, but differ in `scanf()`.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/sd4jrj455

Comment: @0___________, Not sure what your point is? Is it just confirming that integer promotion does occur?

Comment: Do the [answers here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4586962/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-h-and-hh-modifiers-for-printf) provide any insight?

Comment: @ikegami  Think about precision and C that predated the distinction between `signed int` and `unsigned int` invoking UB if printed with `%x` or simlilar.  For example, I'm pretty sure `%x` is not UB when passed a `signed int` in C89.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Consider this example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    unsigned short x = 32770;
    printf("%d\n", x) ;  // (1)
    printf("%u\n", x) ;  // (2)
}
```

On a typical 16-bit implementation, the default argument promotions take `unsigned short` to `unsigned int`, whereas on a typical 32-bit implementation, `unsigned short` becomes `int`.

So on the 16-bit system (1) is UB and (2) is correct, but on the 32-bit system, (1) is correct and (2) it can be debated whether correct or UB.

Using `%hu` for printing `x` works on all systems and you don't have to think about these issues.

A similar example could be constructed for `char` on systems with `sizeof(int) == 1`.

Comment: @ikegami see 7.21.6.1/8 . The `u` specifier only has defined behaviour for an  `unsigned int` argument.  The standard permits a compiler to use different registers for passing `int` than `unsigned int`;  when I say "can be debated" I basically mean that people pretend the standard is defective on this point and that they can get away with passing signed ints to `%u`

Comment: @ikegami line (2) in my program provides `int` argument on a typical 32-bit system. You even quoted the rule in your previous comment, 32-bit `int` can represent all of the values of 16-bit `unsigned short`

Comment: You should add your answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4586962/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-h-and-hh-modifiers-for-printf) Noone mentioned it!

Comment: @ikegami maybe a mod could merge the questions, idk

Comment: I've never seen that happen in SO. We can close as duplicate, which I'm going to have to do even though I think this is the real answer and it's not provided there.

Comment: I have seen it happen

Comment: If we close this as a dup, I will encourage M.M. to copy-and-paste this excellent answer there.

Answer (score 1):

It's for backwards compatibility.

In a draft version of the C89 standard, [printing a signed `int`, `short` or `char` with the `%x`format specifier is not undefined behavior](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c89/c89-draft.html#4.9.6.1):

> d, i, o, u, x, X The int argument is converted to signed decimal ( d or i ), unsigned octal ( o ), unsigned decimal ( u ), or unsigned hexadecimal notation ( x or X ); the letters abcdef are used for x conversion and the letters ABCDEF for X conversion. The precision specifies the minimum number of digits to appear; if the value being converted can be represented in fewer digits, it will be expanded with leading zeros. The default precision is 1. The result of converting a zero value with an explicit precision of zero is no characters.

This seems to document that pre-standardized C, using format specifiers such as `%x` for *signed* values was an existing practice, thus a preexisting code base using `h` and `hh` length modifiers likely existed.

Without the `h` and `hh` length modifiers, `signed char` values with a bit pattern `0xFF` would be printed on a 32-bit-`int` system as `0xFFFFFFFF` if printed with a simple `%X` format specifier.

Comment: @ikegami Find that in the C89 standard: http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c89/c89-draft.html#4.9.6.1

Comment: That error has been fixed in newer version "*The `unsigned int` argument is converted to unsigned octal (o), unsigned decimal (u), or unsigned hexadecimal notation (x or X)*", See also [printf](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf)

Comment: The C89 text is clearly defective as it only talks about "The int argument" whereas the argument might actually be `unsigned int`.  Unless you would like to  claim that `printf("%u", 1u);` is UB in C89 of course.

Comment: I have edited the comment to include actual standard quote. You're using an outdated reference, which is clearly buggy as M.M said. And yes, I do seriously trust cppreference more than you :)

Comment: That is not the C89 standard. It is some draft. The actual ANSI/ISO 9899-1990 standard, in clause 7.9.6.1 (not 4.9.6.1!) has one entry for “`d`, `i`” that says “The `int` argument…” and  another for “`o`, `u`, `x`, `X`” that says “The `unsigned int` argument…”

Comment: @EricPostpischil OK, I'll assume you have a better link then?

Comment: @Andrew Henle, Trust but verify, which I did. The latest spec (well, N2176) clearly says `unsigned int`

Comment: I have a PDF of a scan of the printed standard. It is no longer available at the URL from which I obtained it.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I saved a copy of that link a few years ago and it does not mention `hh` in the 4.9.6.1 section .  (The site is currently not serving the whole page for me, it gets to 30% and stops)

Comment: shit, but you did say it's for backwards compatibility, which I totally missed. Does anyone actually have access to the C89?

Comment: @EricPostpischil I'll update to reflect I'm quoting a draft.  Because the draft is proof that using `%x` for signed integers did exist for pre-standardized C, so the `h` and `hh` flags would be kept for backwards compatiblity.

Comment: @ikegami It's the first line.  ;-)

Comment: @EricPostpischil ISO C90 and ANSI C89 are different documents , I wonder whether that splitting of `d`, `i` from the unsigned specifiers occurred between the draft and ANSI C89, or between C89 and C90.  I suspect the former, as I have heard C89 and C90 are identical other than paragraph numbering

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the `hh` specifier specifically, it was explicitly added in C99 in order to utilize printing of all the default fixed size types from `stdint.h`/`inttypes.h`. C99 mades the types `int_leastn_t` from 8 to 64, mandatory, so there was a need for corresponding format specifiers.

From the C99 rationale 5.10, §7.19.6.1 (`fprintf`):

> The `%hh` and `%ll` length modifiers were added in C99 (see §7.19.6.2).

§7.19.6.2 (`fscanf`):

> *A new feature of C99*: The `hh` and `ll` length modifiers were added in C99. `ll` supports the new long long int type. `hh` adds the ability to treat character types the same as all other integer types; this can be useful in implementing macros such as `SCNd8` in `<inttypes.h>` (see 7.18).

Before C99, there was just `d`, `h` and `l` for printing integer types. In C99, a conventional implementation could for example define `inttypes.h` specifiers as:

```
#define SCNi8   hh
#define SCNi16   h
#define SCNi32   d
#define SCNi64  ll
```

And now the default argument promotions becomes the head ache of the `printf`/`scanf` implementation, rather than the `inttypes.h` implementation.

Comment: The passage you quoted says it was added for `scanf` (nor for `printf` as you claim), and it's very easy to see why it's needed for `scanf` (where the same promotion doesn't occur since pointers are passed as arguments). This does not answer the question.

Comment: @ikegami C99 strived to make printf and scanf consistent. They fixed the `%lf` specifier for printf for example. After fixing that, what would they add new specifiers to scanf but not to printf? Luckily they didn't. Like it or not, this _was_ the reason `hh` got added to the language.

Comment: That *would* be an answer (though claiming it's for consistency is contradicted by the fact that they are actually needed with printf in some situations as pointed out by the earlier answers.) I commented on what you *did* answer.

Comment: @ikegami Added reference for printf.

Answer (score 0):

They are not there for `printf()` usage, but for `scanf()` to be able to use references to `short` integers and `char` integers.  For uniformity and completeness, they are accepted for `printf()` functions, but they are undistinguisable, as the vaarg parameters of `printf()` are promoted to `int` for all parameters that are of types `short` and `char` integer values.  So they are equivalent in `printf()` but not in `scanf()` and friends.